# Librerias de c++ y c

Tags: c++, c

Buenos días.
Me gustaría saber algunos conceptos sobre las librerías de c++ y c. 
Mi primera pregunta seria  porqué se puede utilizar stdio.h en c++ ademas de iostream, y cual es mejor de utilizar a fin de cuentas, ademas otra pregunta sería  que diferencia hay entre escribir "stdlib.h" y "cstdlib" todo eso en c++. Vengo de estudiar c y ahora estoy empezando con c++ y no tengo claro las diferencias.

Comment: Hola Raul, bienvenido. No olvides pasar por el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más del funcionamiento del sitio. Y procura no utilizar expresiones como "la mejor" ya que todo es subjetivo o muy relacionado con la situacion y necesidades. Un saludo!

Answer (score 19):

> ¿Por qué se puede utilizar `stdio.h` en C++ ademas de `iostream`?

#### El compilador.

En muchas ocasiones, el compilador usado para C++ y C es el mismo, tan sólo cambia la configuración del compilador para hacer compilaciones en uno u otro modo. Por este motivo no es raro que las librerías de ambos lenguajes estén disponibles mutuamente, es decir: también podrías incluir `<iostream>` en un código C pero no te serviría de nada ya que C++ dispone de palabras clave diferentes ([`template`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) o [`namespace`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) no existen en C), algunas palabras clave no tienen el mismo significado (por ejemplo `auto`<sup>1</sup> o `register`<sup>2</sup>) e incluso C++ ha deprecado elementos que en C siguen siendo válidos (como los [dígrafos o trígrafos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADgrafos_y_tr%C3%ADgrafos#C)).

#### Costumbre.

Muchos programadores cuyo lenguaje principal ha sido durante años C trabajan también con C++. También, programadores de ciertas generaciones han sido educados con C en universiadaes y centros educativos antes que con C++ y para estos programadores suele ser más cómodo usar utilidades, sintaxis y constructos de C antes que aproximaciones de C++ incluso si están programando C++; no podrían hacer esto de no ser por la…

#### Compatibilidad con C.

C++ se basa en C y evoluciona a partir de éste. El comité de estándares de C++ hace muchos esfuerzos por mantener una compatibilidad con C (aunque esto, a cada año que pasa causa más controversia, tal vez dejen de preocuparse por esta compatibilidad en el futuro). Gracias a los esfuerzos realizados en esta compatibilidad, cualquier código de C es compilable en C++ usando las librerías adecuadas y con cambios mínimos (o ninguno).

> ¿Qué diferencia hay entre escribir `"stdlib.h"` y `"cstdlib"`.

C++ adapta muchas de las librerías de C a su propia idiosincrasia, clasificando funciones en espacios de nombres o transformando algunas funciones en plantillas, cuando una librería de C ha sido adaptada a C++ su archivo recibe una `c` como prefijo y se le elimina la extensión, aquí tienes un [listado de archivos de cabecera C y su cabecera adaptada en C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/):

| C++ | C |
| --- | --- |
| cassert | assert.h |
| cctype | ctype.h |
| cerrno | errno.h |
| cfloat | float.h |
| ciso646 | iso646.h |
| climits | limits.h |
| clocale | locale.h |
| cmath | math.h |
| csetjmp | setjmp.h |
| csignal | signal.h |
| cstdarg | stdarg.h |
| cstdbool | stdbool.h |
| cstddef | stddef.h |
| cstdint | stdint.h |
| cstdio | stdio.h |
| cstdlib | stdlib.h |
| cstring | string.h |
| ctime | time.h |
| cuchar | uchar.h |
| cwchar | wchar.h |
| cwctype | wctype.h |

> ¿Cuál es mejor de utilizar?

Utiliza la colección de cabeceras específica de cada lenguaje, es decir: en C usa `stdio.h` y si necesitas algo de esa librería en C++ usa `cstdio`.

---

<sup>1</sup>En C `auto` es un especificador de almacenamiento (la misma categoría que `static`, por ejemplo) mientras que [en C++ se usa para la deducción estática de tipos](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

<sup>2</sup>En C `register` se usa para indicar al compilador que la variable cualificada con esta palabra clave será muy usada y el programador recomienda que sea almacenada en un registro de procesador, en C++ esta palabra clave está deprecada (a partir de C++17).

Comment: Muchas gracias, la tabla me va a servir mucho.

Comment: @Raul la tabla es una conversión muy sencilla... a la librería 'x.h' le quitas la extensión y le añades como prefijo una 'c'. Así `x.h <-> cx`

Comment: @eferion tal y como explico justo encima de la tabla xD

Comment: Lo se, solo quería remarcárselo porque con su comentario me ha dado la impresión de que no ha interiorizado esa parte.

Comment: otra palabra que da warning en c++ es el puntero al puntero void: void**

Answer (score 7):

> ¿Porqué se puede utilizar `stdio.h` en c++ ademas de `iostream`?

Al principio, lo que hoy conocemos como C++ no eran sino un compendio de macros pensadas para que C se comportase como un lenguaje orientado a objetos. Con el tiempo se hizo necesario crear un lenguaje propio y ahí nació C++.

Debido a esa historia común, las librerías de C han sido siempre compartidas por C++ y, por compatibilidad, lo seguirán siendo.

En el caso de `cstdio`, esta librería existe únicamente para mantener la coherencia con la librería estándar propia de C++, donde ninguna librería incluye la extensión `.h`.

En el caso de `iostream` tenemos una librería propia de C++ que puede aprovechar todas las bondades de dicho lenguaje. Así pone a nuestra disposición una serie de facilidades de entrada/salida con multitud de utilidades que además podemos ampliar y configurar a nuestro antojo (Así, por ejemplo, podemos preparar nuestras clases para que puedan imprimirse por pantalla usando el operador de inserción `std::cout << miClase`, cosa que en C es impensable).

Por otro lado, el hecho de que existan `stdio.h` e `iostream` no es del todo malo:

- La gente que viene de C puede aprovecharse de una curva de aprendizaje más suave ya que puede reaprovechar buena parte del conocimiento que ya posee.
- Hay operaciones que pueden resultar más sencillas de implementar con las librerías de C
- Disponer de las librerías de C aumenta la compatibilidad entre ambos lenguajes.

> ¿que diferencia hay entre escribir `stdlib.h` y `cstdlib`?

Absolutamente ninguna. La diferencia la encuentras al compilar en C o compilar en C++. Las librerías disponibles en C++ (tanto `stdio.h` como `cstdio`) añaden una versión de las funciones bajo el espacio de nombres `std`, cosa que por motivos obvios no se puede hacer en C.

> ¿Cual es mejor de utilizar?

Dado que no hay diferencias, siéntete libre de utilizar la versión que más te guste.

Comment: Muchas gracias, te explicas muy bien.

Comment: No es del todo cierto que no existan diferencias entre `xxxx.h` y `cxxxx`, por ejemplo en `math.h` disponemos de varias versiones de `ceil` (`ceil`, `ceilf` y `ceill`) mientras que en `cmath` cuatro sobrecargas (además de estar en el espacio de nombres `std`).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster No olvidemos que math es una librería "_diferente_" que al menos antes había que enlazarla de forma explícita para poder usar sus funciones. En lo referente al espacio de nombres, ambas deberían crear las funciones en `std` y en el espacio de nombres global

Comment: Sea como sea, en ese ejemplo no se puede afirmar que no haya "absolutamente ninguna diferencia" entre una librería `xxx.h` y `cxxx`, además C no dispone de espacios de nombres, sólo con eso ya es bastante diferente. Pero sin usar el *controvertido* ejemplo de math, en caso de stdio también tenemos **notables diferencias** para la família `printf` entre [`stdio.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) y [`cstdio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Yo únicamente estoy hablando de trabajar en C++... Al trabajar con C no tiene ningún sentido hablar de las librerías de C++.

Comment: Tiene sentido hablar de las diferencias entre ambas en el momento en que parte de las dudas del usuario es precisamente si existen diferencias :) incluso trabajando exclusivamente en C++ incluyendo `stdio.h` tendrás acceso a `printf_s` pero no existirá dicha función incluyendo `cstdio`

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster De hecho mira, para que te quedes más tranquilo... sacado de la cabecera `cstdio` de mi compilador, línea 42: `#include <stdio.h>`. Así pues lo que dices de que `printf_s` no va a estar disponible en `cstdio`....

Comment: No me aporta ni tranquilidad ni intranquilidad saber ese dato. Simplemente quería remarcar que `xxx.h` y `cxxx` no son lo mismo, ni siquiera si la versión C++ incluye la versión C (el hecho de que una incluya a otra ya es prueba de que no son lo mismo). Puedo decir que `cstdio` puede no tener disponible `printf_s` porque no hay garantías de que así vaya a ser en todos los casos.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster [enlace1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694255/c-cmath-vs-math-h-and-similar-c-prefixed-vs-h-extension-headers) [enlace2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247094/whats-the-difference-between-c-header-files-h-and-c-header-files-hpp). No veo que demasiada gente critique las diferencias que comentas... que una versión tiene 3 funciones y la otra 7... eso es porque por diferencias entre lenguajes determinadas conversiones no son válidas (eso sí en la cabecera .h de un compilador de C++ no vas a encontrar **JAMAS** la implementación de la cabecera del compilador de C)

Comment: Entonces me estás dando la razón: NO se puede decir que "no hay absolutamente ninguna diferencia" entre las cabeceras de C y de C++... si tenemos diferentes funciones, diferentes implementaciones y la existenca o ausencia de espacios de nombres... por mucho que la gente no critique dichas diferencias los archivos no son iguales, de serlo: serían intercambiables y... evidentemente no lo son.

Comment: Alguien me podria explicar de una manera sencilla para que uso "using namespace std", ya que en c nunca lo vi, ademas intentando ver que era por internet, vi que lo desaconsejan por posibles errores

Comment: @Raul si no te importa crea una pregunta nueva o mira si hay preguntas similares

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no te ofusques la pregunta va enfocada desde C++ ya que si no estás comparando churras con merinas. Como bien has dicho otras veces C y C++ son cosas distintas. Preguntarse por las diferencias entre x.h y cx solo tiene sentido si hablas sobre C++ y en este caso **no hay diferencias**.

Comment: @eferion ¡pensé que habíamos quedado en que sí que las hay! Son archivos distintos, con contenido distinto y funciones distintas (incluso cuando C++ incluye C, lo hace para añadir contenido) así que diferencias, haberlas: haylas.

Comment: @Raul [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%c3%a9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%c3%a1ctica) podría serte de ayuda para tu nueva duda.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Entonces ve a los enlaces que te he puesto de StackOverflow en ingles y dedícate a poner negativos y comentarios porque ellos también respaldan lo que digo...

Comment: @eferion Vale, aunque no es mi prioridad... no entiendo cómo se puede andar diciendo que dos cosas distintas son iguales. Acabo de mirar los enlaces que me compartiste, y ninguno de los dos afirma que `cxxx` y `xxx.h` sean lo mismo.