# cstdio vs fstream

Tags: c++

Comparando las dos librerías de streams de ficheros como son cstdio y fstream llego a la conclusión de que hacen exactamente lo mismo. Estoy estudiando C++. ¿Es mejor opcion seguir con la "evolución" del lenguaje y seguir con fstream? Lo unico que creo que hay diferente es que en cstdio están las funciones rename y remove para renombrar y eliminar ficheros. ¿Esto puede hacerse también con fstream?

Comment: Lo mejor es lo que creas que es mejor. psd: -1, porque lo que puedo responder de esta pregunta es demasiado subjetivo.

Comment: No, no puede. Y, dicho esto, voto por cerrarla como *basada en opiniones*.

Comment: [Relacionado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48268/librerias-de-c-y-c).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stdio` (o `cstdio`) es una librería heredada de C mientras que `fstream` es una librería exclusiva de C++. ¿Diferencias? unas cuantas (te enumero algunas):

- `stdio` es heredada de C mientras que `fstream` es propia de C++
- las librerías de entrada salida propias de C++ permiten el uso abstracto y homogéneo de su funcionalidad
- las librerías propias de C++ son extensibles
- las librerías propias de C++ pueden hacer uso de `iomanip`

**`stdio` es heredada de C mientras que `fstream` es propia de C++**

En `stdio` encontrarás una colección de funciones (no clases) pensadas para interactuar con la entrada/salida, mientras que en `fstream` lo que predominan son las clases (por algo es una librería propia de C++).

**las librerías de entrada salida propias de C++ permiten el uso abstracto y homogéneo de su funcionalidad**

Al estar basada en clases, y gracias a que estas clases poseen herencia, es posible implementar mecanismos de entrada salida independientes del del origen o destino final de los datos:

```
// ¿el destino es un fichero? ¿sera la consola? ¿quizas una impresora?
void PrintDatos(std::ostream& out)
{
  out << "abcdefg";
}
```

Esta característica ayuda a reutilizar código. Vale si, alguno me dirá que con `stdio` también se puede hacer:

```
fprintf(stdout,"abcdef");
```

La diferencia está, en este caso, en que hacer uso de esta característica con `stdio` nos va a impedir hacer uso de prácticamente la mitad de la funcionalidad ofrecida por dicha librería ya que las funciones que no admitan como parámetro de entrada un `FILE*` no van a poder ser utilizadas en este contexto. Esto último contrasta con las librerías propias de C++ que no pierden funcionalidad.

**las librerías propias de C++ son extensibles**

Que `fstream`sea una librería propia de C++ implica que se ha diseñado pensando en las características propias de C++ lo que implica que, por ejemplo, su funcionalidad es extensible mediante nuestras propias sobrecargas:

```
struct Test
{
  int valor;
  char caracter;

  Test(int v, char c)
    : valor(v), caracter(c)
  { }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Test const& test)
{
  return out << test.valor << test.caracter; 
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Test> lista { {1,'a'},{2,'b'},{3,'c'},{4,'d'} };

  for( auto& test : lista )
    std::cout << test;
}
```

Un diseño similar sería impensable con `stdio` o, al menos, sería más aparatoso de programar y menos natural, lo que generaría código más complicado de leer.

**las librerías propias de C++ pueden hacer uso de `iomanip`**

Otra característica interesante de la entrada salida propia de C++ es que es posible usar la librería `iomanip` para configurar cómo se va a volcar la información. Esta característica por si sola no aporta gran cosa, pero cuando se combina con las características anteriores permite obtener soluciones bastante elegantes:

```
std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('#') << 45;
```

**Conclusión**

`stdio` existe básicamente porque C++ era en sus inicios una especie de C ligeramente vitaminado. Según C++ se fue desligando de su predecesor ha ido adquiriendo librerías propias para sus propios intereses.

Actualmente `stdio` sirve más como librería de compatibilidad para poder traer a C++ código C. Si estás haciendo código nuevo es preferible usar las librerías propias de C++.