# Pirámide en C++

Tags: c++

Buenas, alguien me podría ayudar a como realizar el código para esta pirámide en entorno consola por favor. Con lenguaje C++.

```
          1
        1 2 1
      1 2 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 3 2 1
  1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Solo logré hacer esto

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;

int main()
{
    int  *n, *x, *y;
    x = new int;
    y = new int;    
    n = new int;

    cout << "Ingrese un numero : ";
    cin >> *n;

    for (*x = 1; *x <= *n ; *x = *x + 1)
    {
        for ( *y = 1; *y <= *n - *x ; *y = *y + 1)
        { 
            cout << "   ";          
        }

        for ( *y = 1; *y < *x + 1; *y = *y + 1)
        {
            cout << "  " << *y;
        }

        cout << endl << "\n";
    }

    getch();
    delete n;
    return 0;
}
```

LO CUAL IMPRIME LA MITAD DE LA PIRAMIDE. (La variable "*n" está con un valor de 6)

```
          1
        1 2
      1 2 3
    1 2 3 4
  1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de ayuda necesitas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No te voy a hacer la tarea, la magia de estos ejercicios esta en pasarsela pensando, sin complicarse haciendolo de la forma mas simple posible.

Estoy suponiendo que tu frustracion te trajo a este sitio(que no es un foro comun y corriente como otros), te recomiendo encarecidamente que leas:

- [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
- [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Mas informacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Bien pues ahora volvamos a tu ejercicio:
Te voy a ayudar con la logica por un momento...
Cuando escribes codigo, tienes que hacerlo lo mas **bonito** que te parece. ¿Por que? porque en algun momento de tu vida tienes q releer ese codigo y creeme si no esta bonito no te va a dar ganas de leerlo ni de estudiarlo, etc.

Para aprender C++ nesesitas [practica](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/), al igual que con las matematicas, esta sucecion es simple, tienes que recorrer hasta *el numero* y luego en reversa, en el codigo de abajo estoy representando este *numero* como la variable numerica entera `int pisos`, luego utilizo los bucles `for` para iterar *o recorrer* la condicion dada, que se lee asi:

*Desde el numero `i` que valdra 1, quiero que recorra hasta el la variable `pisos` que es 6, siempre y cuando `i` al incrementarse, siga siendo menor igual a `pisos`; luego ejecuta por cada vez que `i` se incremente, un `for` que dira; hasta que `j` que vale 1 sea menor a `i`, imprime la diferencia entre `i` e `j`. Luego imprime un salto de linea `cout << endl;` cuando acabes de hacer el `for` con `j`, el bucle `for` con `k` solo imprime la parte acendiente, hasta antes del **numero** .*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int pisos = 6;
    for (int i = 1; i <= pisos; i++) {
        for (int k = 1; k < i ;k++) {
            cout << k << " ";
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            cout << i-j << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El codigo que te escribi resuelve, <strike>a la mitad tu ejercicio</strike>, *te lo pongo todo porque hay mas dificultad en manipular los espacios `" "`*.
Buena suerte!

## Resolucion

Te recomiendo que veas eso solo cuando hayas intentado de todoy aun asi no hayas conseguido sacar la piramide.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int pisos = 6;
    for (int i = 1; i <= pisos; i++) {
        //calcula los espacios a imprimir por la izquierda
        for (int x = 0; x < pisos -i; x++) {
            cout << "  ";
        }
        //imprime crecientemente los numeros hasta 1 antes del limite
        for (int k = 1; k < i ;k++) {
            cout << k << " ";
        }
        //imprime los elementos desde el limite decrecientemente hasta 1
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            cout << i-j << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Efectivamente todo lo que dice PaperBirdMaster es correcto, estas usando librerias inutiles, que nisiquiera son de C++, y el uso de punteros es basicamtente *ahogarse en un vaso de agua*, como puedes notar en mi resolucion, puedes tener la solucion al problema sencillamente, no deseo usar `string` porque no quiero sumergirme en C++, lo hago solo usando matematica sencilla.

*El ultimo `for` que agregue con `x` lo que hace es imprimir la cantidad de espacios que nesesitamos, si te dijas la logica esta en que es el mismo triangulo pero invertido(volteado de cabeza) en espacios, si teniamos el limite que era 6, entonces imprimimos 5 espacios, porque son los 6 menos el caracter, salen 5. Y asi sucecivamente, hasta que el limite es 0 espacios y lleno de caracteres. Yo te pongo `"  "` porque le agregamos un espacio a cada caracter o numero por elemento, asi que para que se acomode en la consola, le puse 2 espacios para asi verlo legible.*

Answer (score 4):

Tienes una serie de problemas y fallos de concepto que te conviene abordar.

#### Incluyes cabeceras incorrectas, que no usas.

Tanto `<conio.h>` [`<stdio.h>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io) son cabeceras del lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c) no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) y no deben ser usadas si compilas como C++ (en ocasiones ni siquiera podrán ser usadas). Para más detalles acerca de ello consulta [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48268/librerias-de-c-y-c). Además de ser cabeceras que no corresponden con el lenguaje que pretendes usar, no usas ninguna de sus utilidades que contienen.

#### El espacio de nombres `Sytem` no existe.

No se qué significa `using namespace System;` pero ese espacio de nombres ni existe ni está contenido en ninguna de las cabeceras que incluyes, tal vez se trate de algo que no has compartido en tu código.

#### No necesitas punteros, pero si los necesitas debes borrarlos al final.

El lenguaje C++ moderno está intentando que los punteros en crudo queden en desuso. Tus variables `x`, `y` y `n` son punteros en crudo que podrían ser substituidas por enteros (`int`) normales. Si por algún motivo tienes que usarlas como punteros al final no debes borrar (`delete`) sólo `n`, deberás borrar todas ellas:

```
int main()
{
    int  *n, *x, *y;
    x = new int;
    y = new int;    
    n = new int;

    // Hacer cosas...

    delete n;
    delete x; // <-- borrar x
    delete y; // <-- borrar y
    return 0;
}
```

Pero si quieres programar C++ moderno deberías substituir los punteros por [`std::unique_ptr`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) de la cabecera [`<memory>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory):

```
using pint = std::unique_ptr<int>;

pint  n, x, y;
x.reset(new int);
y.reset(new int);
n.reset(new int);
```

Usando `std::unique_ptr` sólo debes preocuparte de solicitar la memoria, que el propio objeto se ocupa de liberarla, está preparado para funcionar de la misma manera que un puntero por lo que el resto del código que escribiste funcionará igual.

#### Solución.

El ejercicio de la pirámide de números es sencillo una vez se descubre el patrón:

1. La cantidad de espacios a la izquierda de cada piso de la pirámide es siempre `(n - piso - 1) * 2` (asumiendo que los pisos se indexan en `0`).
2. Los números incrementan desde el valor `1` siempre en hasta alcanzar el valor `piso`, tras ello decrementan hasta alcanzar el valor `1`.

Para conseguir el primer punto, puedes usar la clase `std::string`, que dispone de un [constructor](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) que te permite construir una cadena mediante la repetición de una cantidad de caracteres:

```
//                                           vvv <-- Queremos una cadena de espacios
std::cout << std::string((n - piso - 1) * 2, ' ');
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- La cadena tiene todos estos elementos
```

Para el segundo punto un par de bucles anidados en el bucle de piso sería suficiente:

```
    // Bucle ascendente:
    for (; valor <= limite; ++valor) std::cout << ' ' << valor;
    // Bucle descendente:
    for (valor -= 2; valor >= 1; --valor) std::cout << ' ' << valor;
```

La variable `limite` será el valor del piso incrementado en uno y el valor siempre debería empezar en `1`.