# Undefined reference to `WinMain@16' c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
class facturar //clase: estructura con ventajas sencillas pero ponentes, y facturar es el nombre de la clase
{
      public: //Este tipo de clase peromite que los datos se puedan ver sin ocultar nada 
        string nom,dirc,apll;
        string mar,mod,colr; //string se maneja para los datos tipo texto 
        double total,precio,sub,iva; // para hacer los calculos patematicos 
        int opc,cant;
        void ejemplo()
        {
             do //ciclo de repeticion miestras la condicion sea verdadera 
        {
             precio=1400000;
             cout <<("|***********************MENU DE FACTURACION************************|\n");
             cout <<("|Solo por el día de hoy todas nuetras computadoras cuestan $1400000|\n\n");

             cout <<("Dame tu nombre:\n");
             getline (cin,nom); //getline almecena datos de texto

             cout <<("Dame tu apellido\n");
             getline (cin,apll);

             cout <<("Dame tu direccion:\n");
             getline (cin,dirc);


             cout <<("\n\nQue marca de computadora quieres\n");
             cout <<("SAMSUNG\n");
             cout <<("LG\n");
             cout <<("APPLE\n");
             getline (cin,mar);

             cout <<("Que modelo quieres\n");
             cout <<("XPRO584.0\n");
             cout <<("ZUTD5648\n");
             cout <<("PRDO8999\n");
             getline (cin,mod);

             cout <<("De que color la quieres\n");
             cout <<("Negra\n");
             cout <<("Gris\n");
             cout <<("Blanca\n");
             getline (cin,colr);

             cout <<("\n\nCuantas deseas comprar");
             cin >>cant;

             sub=cant*precio;
             iva=sub*0.19;
             total=sub*iva;


cout <<("*****************Recibo de compra*****************");   //Se pone lo que debe de aparecer en la pantalla y las variables de cada una
cout <<("\n\nNombre:")<<nom<<("Apellido:\n")<<apll;       
cout <<("Direccion:\n")<<dirc;      

cout <<("Producto, computadora marca:\n")<<mar;
cout <<("Modelo:\n")<<mod;
cout <<("Color:\n")<<colr;

cout <<("\n\n******************Precio final******************\n");
cout <<("Cantidad:")<<cant;
cout <<("Subproducto;")<<sub;
cout <<("IVA:")<<iva;
cout <<("Total")<<total;
getch (); // Pausa para que se vea el resultado

system ("cls"); //Limpia la pantalla 

cout <<("Presiona -1 para salir");
cin >>opc;

}
while (opc!=-1);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás compilando una aplicación de ventana de Windows sin facilitarle al compilador la función [WinMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx).

Por otro lado usas cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c) en un programa [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b); no deberías usar `<conio.h>`, `<stdio.h>` ni `<math.h>` si no sus versiones adaptadas a C++: `<cstdio>` y `<cmath>` ([`<conio.h>` no tiene equivalente en C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122206/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-las-flechas-direccionales-en-c/122350#122350)); además `<cstdio>` e `<iostream>` tienen las mismas funcionalidades (comunicarse con el usuario) así que deberían ser mútuamente excluyentes.