# ¿Cómo guardar información de un fichero a una variable?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    char capitulo[4];
    char versiculo[4];
    char texto_biblia[175];
    }texto_biblico;

texto_biblico *textoo;

void leer_archivo();
void almacenar_archivo();
void menu();

void leer_archivo(){
    system("cls");//limpio pantalla al momento de ingresar al menu
    string nfichero; //= "pruebasProyecto2.txt";
    cout << "INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO:\n";
    cin >> nfichero;
    nfichero += ".txt";
    char cadena [150];
    ifstream fichero;//leo el archivo
    fichero.open(nfichero.c_str(),ios::in);//abro el archivo, y le copio lo que viene del archivo a la varaible string
    if (!fichero.fail()){//condicion si el archivo falla
        fichero.getline(cadena, 175, '\n');
    while (!fichero.eof()){
        cout << cadena << endl;
        fichero.getline(cadena, 175, '\n');
    }
    fichero.close();//cierra el archvo
    int n = strlen(cadena);
    textoo = (texto_biblico*)malloc(n*sizeof(texto_biblico));
    cout << textoo;
    }
    else {
        cout << "EL ARCHIVO NO SE PUDO ABRIR\n";
    }

}

//void almacenar_archivo(){
  //  int dos_puntos =0, espacio_blanco = 0,
//}

void menu(){
    int menu_principal;
    cout << "MENU PRINICIPAL LECTURA DE CAPITULO DE LA SANTA BIBLIA" << endl;
    cout << "1.LEER NUEVO ARCHIVO .TXT CON CONTENIDO BIBLLICO" << endl;
    cout << "2.VISUALIZAR VERSICULOS EN PANTALLA (INGRESE SOLO NUMERO DE CAPITULO Y VERSICULO)" << endl;
    cout << "3.CERRAR SESION" << endl;
    cin >> menu_principal;
    while(menu_principal < 3){
        switch (menu_principal){
        case 1:leer_archivo();}
    menu_principal++;}
}

int main (){
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: podrias poner una estrutura del archivo y una breve explicacion de lo q deberia hacer cuando va ha leer el archivo, y en q parte tienes tu archivo

Comment: fijate que tengo que que leer el archivo en pantalla y de ese archivo que tiene tengo que guardar informacion en una variable tipo cha

Answer (score 3):

C++ ofrece unas herramientas que abstraen la lectura de datos de diferentes fuentes hacia variables del programa, son conocidos como flujos de datos (*stream* en Inglés).

Estas abstracciones pueden ser la consola (`std::cin`), un archivo (`std::ifstream`) o incluso texto (`std::istringstream`). Todas estas abstracciones tienen también una versión de salida, de manera que puedes escribir en la consola (`std::cout`), en un archivo (`std::ofstream`) o en una variable de texto (`std::ostringstream`).

> ¿Cómo guardar información de un fichero a una variable?

Eso depende mucho de cómo se haya guardado la información en el fichero; en otras palabras: la lectura de datos de un fichero a una variable dependerá de cómo se haya escrito desde el programa a dicho fichero. En tu caso dispones de un objeto de tamaño fijo:

```
struct texto_biblico {
    char capitulo[4]{};
    char versiculo[4]{};
    char texto_biblia[175]{};
};
```

Si lo guardas en archivo como un paquete de 183 bytes (posiblemente el resultado de `sizeof(texto_biblico)`), podrás leerlo como paquete completo:

```
texto_biblico ap_13_18 {
    "13",
    "18",
    "Aquí hay sabiduría. El que tiene entendimiento,"
    "cuente el número de la bestia, pues es número de hombre."
    "Y su número es seiscientos sesenta y seis.",
};

if (std::ofstream apocalipsis{"apocalipsis.txt"}) {
    apocalipsis.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&ap_13_18), sizeof(ap_13_18));
}
```

La función [`std::ofstream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) permite escribir un paquete de datos de tamaño determinado, su análoga para la lectura es [`std::ifstream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) de un flujo de entrada:

```
texto_biblico pasaje{};

if (std::ifstream archivo{"apocalipsis.txt"}) {
    archivo.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&pasaje), sizeof(ap_13_18));
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- En C++ `struct` no forma parte del tipo de datos, no necesitas declarar estructuras añadiendo esa palabra clave ni usar alias de tipos para crear un tipo que incorpre esa palabra clave.
- C y C++ son lenguajes diferentes con distinta idiosincrasia, es posible usar las cabeceras de C en C++ pero para un mejor uso muchas de las cabeceras estándar de C se han adaptado a C++ clasificando funciones en espacios de nombres o transformando algunas funciones en plantillas, cuando una librería de C ha sido adaptada a C++ su archivo recibe una c como prefijo y se le elimina la extensión, no debes usar `<stdio.h>` o `<stdlib.h>` si no `<cstdio>` y `<cstdlib>`, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48268/librerias-de-c-y-c/48305#48305) para conocer más detalles al respecto.
- La cabecera `<conio.h>` no es estándar (por eso carece de equivalente en C++, que sería llamada `<cconio>`), lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122206/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-las-flechas-direccionales-en-c/122350#122350) para conocer más detalles al respecto.
- Las cabeceras `<stdio.h>` e `<iostream>` son equivalentes, ambas sirven para comunicarse con el usuario, ya que estás programando en C++ usa sólo `<iostream>`.
- Procura no abusar de `using namespace std`, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%C3%A9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica) para saber por qué.
- La función `malloc` forma parte de C, no de C++. Aunque no esté prohibido usarla en C++ lo adecuado es usar `new` y `delete`.

#### Propuesta.

Teniendo en cuenta todo lo anterior, tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// Sin el typedef
struct texto_biblico {
    // Al añadir las llaves, los arreglos se inicializarán vacíos
    char capitulo[4]{};
    char versiculo[4]{};
    char texto_biblia[175]{};
};

void leer_archivo(){
    std::string nfichero;

    std::cout << "INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO:\n";
    std::cin >> nfichero;

    /* Se define 'fichero' en la sentencia 'if' anclando
    su ciclo de vida al ámbito del 'if'. Al finalizar el
    ciclo de vida de 'fichero' se llamará a 'close' de
    manera automática. */
    if (std::ifstream fichero{nfichero + ".txt"}) {
        texto_biblico tb{};

        while (fichero.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tb), sizeof(tb))) {
            std::cout << "Leído Texto " << tb.capitulo << '-' << tb.versiculo
                      << '\n' << tb.texto_biblia;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "EL ARCHIVO NO SE PUDO ABRIR\n";
    }
    // Aqui fichero.close() se ha llamado automáticamente.
}

void almacenar_archivo(){
    std::string nfichero;

    std::cout << "INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO:\n";
    std::cin >> nfichero;

    if (std::ofstream fichero{nfichero + ".txt"}) {
        texto_biblico tb{};
        std::cout << "\nCapitulo: ";
        std::cin >> tb.capitulo;
        std::cout << "\nVersiculo: ";
        std::cin >> tb.versiculo;
        std::cout << "\nTexto: ";
        std::cin >> tb.texto_biblia;

        fichero.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&tb), sizeof(tb));
    } else {
        std::cout << "EL ARCHIVO NO SE PUDO ABRIR\n";
    }
    // Aqui fichero.close() se ha llamado automáticamente.
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias a todos

Comment: En el segundo párrafo, donde dice "en un archivo (`std::cout`)", no debería decir "en un archivo (`std::ofstream`)"?

Comment: ¡Bien visto @Xam ! Lo corrijo.

Answer (score 1):

probe tu programa y funciona bien, solo arroja algo raro al final, intenta leer todas las lineas una a una y las metiendo en una variable, al final la imprimes

```
ifstream fichero;
fichero.open("archivo.txt",ios::in);
if (!fichero.fail()){
    string texto="",temporal="";
    while (!fichero.eof()){
         getline(fichero, temporal);
        texto += temporal+"\n";
    }
    fichero.close();
    cout<<texto;
}
```