# ¿Cómo puedo escribir con scanf en la clase en C++?

Tags: c++

Éste es mi código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

class operaciones  {

    public: 

    int num1;
    int num2;

    public:

        operaciones( int _num1, int _num2);

        void suma();
        void resta();
        void multiplicacion();
        void division();
        void dato();
};

operaciones::operaciones(int _num1, int _num2)
{
    num1 = _num1;
    num2 = _num2;
}

void operaciones::suma()
{
    int s;
    s = num1 + num2;

    printf("El resultado de la suma es: %d\n",s);
}

void operaciones::resta()
{
    int r;
    r = num1 + num2;

    printf("El resultado de la resta es: %d\n",r); 
}

void operaciones::multiplicacion()
{
    int m;
    m = num1 * num2;

    printf("El resultado de la multiplicacion es: %d\n",m);
}

void operaciones::division()
{
    float d;
    d = num1/num2;

    printf("El resultado de la division es: %f\n",d);
}

void operaciones::dato()
{

printf("Escribir un numero\n");  //Necesito ayuda aquí, para que el usuario ingrese un valor y sea retornado en el programa principal

    scanf("%f"&operaciones.num1);

    printf("Escribir un numero\n");
    scanf("%f"&operaciones.num2);
}

int main()
{


    operaciones o(); // osease aquí y me de los resultados

    o.suma();
    o.resta();
    o.multiplicacion();
    o.division();

}
```

Comment: Resulta curioso que en todas las llamadas a funciones, separas los argumentos con comas ... ¡ menos en las llamadas a `scanf( )` !

Comment: Holaa..!! no sirve, me marcan errores, pero fue una gran observacion

Comment: Si pusieras los errores en cuestión, creo que sería mas fácil ayudarte :-)

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Cómo puedo escribir con scanf en la clase en C++?

No lo hagas, `printf` y `scanf` son las funciones de lectura de consola de C, en C++ se usan los objetos *stream*: [`std::cout`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) y [`std::cin`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin).

Además:

- La cabecera [`<stdio.h>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) es de [c](/questions/tagged/c) no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Las cabeceras de C disponen de una versión adaptada a C++ que tiene el prefijo **`c`** y carece de extensión. Si realmente necesitas usar las cabeceras de C (que nunca será el caso) debes usar los equivalentes de C++ [`<cstdio>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio). Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber por qué.
- La cabecera `<conio.h>` ni siquera es estándar C y no existe en C++, consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/122350/2742) para saber por qué.

Dicho esto, tu problema está en la manera en que llamas a `scanf`:

```
scanf("%f"&operaciones.num1);
// ...
scanf("%f"&operaciones.num2);
```

Estás operando un literal de cadena de caracteres `"%f"` contra dos enteros (`operaciones::num1` y `operaciones::num2`) mediante el operador de AND binario `&`. En otras palabras, le estás pasando a `scanf` el resultado de evaluar la expresión que dice "*Hazme una comparación binaria de tipo AND entre la dirección de memoria de la cadena `"%f"` y este `int`*"; o eso haría si el código siquiera compilase.

Las instrucciones `operaciones.num1` y `operaciones.num2` no son válidas, `operaciones` es el nombre de un objeto y `num1`/`num2` son miembros de dicho objeto, para acceder a miembros de un objeto necesitas una **instancia** del objeto, no el nombre del mismo, dado que la llamada se realiza en el contexto de la propia clase, no necesitas anteponer el nombre de la misma:

```
void operaciones::dato()
{    
    printf("Escribir un numero\n");
//            v <--- Coma, para indicar que es un segundo parámetro
    scanf("%f", &num1); // No precedemos 'num1' con el nombre de la clase
//              ^ <--- Operador de "dirección de"

    printf("Escribir un numero\n");
//            v <--- Coma, para indicar que es un segundo parámetro
    scanf("%f", &num2); // No precedemos 'num2' con el nombre de la clase
//              ^ <--- Operador de "dirección de"
}
```

Pero como ya he dicho, en C++ deberías usar `std::cout` y `std::cin`:

```
void operaciones::dato()
{    
    std::cout << "Escribir un numero\n";
    std::cin >> num1;

    std::cout << "Escribir un numero\n";
    std::cin >> num2;
}
```