# error al poner clrscr ();

Tags: c

Espero me puedan ayudar a ver mi error: ¿Por qué me da error el la función clrscr
y por qué a la par del `main` hay que poner (void)?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main (void)/*porque el void?*/
{
    clrscr (); /*error del clrscr no sé por qué me sale error */

    int i,n,v[100];

    printf ("Ingrese la cantidad de elementos:\n");

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese un elemento: ");

        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
    }
    printf("\nLos elementos ingresados son:\n");

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",v[i]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: ¿Que error?, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Son dos preguntas diferentes. Para empezar, `clrscr()` no es una función de C estándar. Es una extensión al lenguaje que se introdujo en [Lattice C y se usó en el popular Borland Turbo C (la cabecera es `conio.h`)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) y funciona únicamente en DOS/Windows. Para continuar, `main` debe devolver un entero y tener dos parámetros (un entero con el número de parámetros y una matriz de cadenas de caracteres), aunque no pasa nada si se define de forma que no tenga parámetros de entrada (`void`) si no vas a hacer uso de ellos.

Answer (score 3):

#### ¿Por qué me da error el la función `clrscr`?

La función `clrscr` debería estar definida en la cabecera `<conio.h>`, la cuál [no forma parte del estándar de C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/122350/2742), esto implica que pueden haber versiones de dicha cabecera que no dispongan de dicha función.

Si consultamos la [información al respecto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) que nos ofrece la Wikipedia<sup>1</sup> (resaltado mío):

> conio.h (*console input/output, consola de entrada/salida*) es un [archivo de cabecera](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_de_cabecera) escrito en [C](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n)) usado mayormente por los compiladores de MS-DOS para proveer un sistema de [E/S](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perif%C3%A9rico_de_entrada/salida) por consola.​ Éste **no es parte de la [biblioteca estándar de C](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblioteca_est%C3%A1ndar_de_C) o [ISO C](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_C), ni está definida por [POSIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)**.
>
> **Las funciones de biblioteca declaradas por `conio.h` varían ligeramente dependiendo el compilador**. Originalmente implementada en Lattice C, las funciones eran mapeadas directamente a las primeras pocas funciones INT 21H de DOS. La biblioteca provista por [Borland Turbo C](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C) no usaba la DOS API pero accedía a la memoria de vídeo directamente para la salida y usaba [llamadas de interrupción de la BIOS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llamada_de_interrupci%C3%B3n_del_BIOS). Esta biblioteca contiene funciones adicionales inspiradas en las funciones de [Turbo Pascal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal).

---

#### `main (void)/*porque el void?*/{`

En el lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c), hay tres maneras de describir los parámetros que recibirá una función:

- Parámetros explícitos: La función recibirá como argumentos aquellos parámetros que se definan:

  ```
    void función(int a, int b, int c);
  ```
- Parámetros desconocidos: La función puede recibir un número indeterminado de argumentos de tipos indefinidos:

  ```
    void función();
  ```
- Sin parámetros: La función no espera ningún argumento.

  ```
    void función(void);
  ```

Ese `void` indica que `main` no acepta argumentos.

---

<sup>1</sup> Y la puntualización del maestro [OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia): `clrscr()` no es una función de C estándar. Es una extensión al lenguaje que se introdujo en [Lattice C y se usó en el popular Borland Turbo C (la cabecera es `conio.h`)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) y funciona únicamente en DOS/Windows.

Comment: Para que una función en C tenga parámetros desconocidos, necesita ser definido como "variadic", algo como esto: `void func(int b,...);`

Comment: @MrDave1999 [No estés tan seguro](https://tio.run/##S00uKNBN/v9fOTMvOac0JVXBprgkJTNfL8OOi6ssPzNFIU1D05qLKzOvRCE3MTNPAySmyVXNxZmmYWhoqKNgZGSko2BsbAxUxFmUWlJalKdgYM1Vi9AMUltQBNSfphEf7xbq5xzi6e8XHw9UX/v/PwA "ecpp + C (gcc) – Try It Online").