# separar datos de un arreglo en arreglos de pares y otro de impares

Tags: c++

intenté ingresar N números a mi arreglo y separarlos en arreglos diferentes dependiendo si son impar o par utilizando switch, pero al mostrarlos en consola aparecieron números sin sentido y de varios dígitos, cual pudo haber sido mi error?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int A[100],n;
    int B[100], C[100];
    cout<<"Digite el numero de elementos que tendra el arreglo: ";
    cin>>n;
    
    for(int i= 0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"Digite un numero: ";
        cin>>A[i];      
    }
    
    for (int i = 0, par = 0, impar = 0; i != 100; ++i)
    switch (A[i] % 2)
    {
        case 0: // Par.
            B[par++] = A[i];
            break;
        case 1: // Impar.
            C[impar++] = A[i];
            break;
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    cout << B[i] << endl;     
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cout << C[i] << endl;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Si intentas expresar en lenguaje natural los dos últimos bucles `for` te darás cuenta del error. ¿Qué haría tu programa si le dieras `n=10` números todos pares?

Comment: Como comenta @juanrpozo tu problema son los limites de los `for`, recomendaria que `par` e `impar` las declares fuera del `for`, ya que estas variables contean la cantidad de elmentos agreagados a cada arreaglo, por ende las uses como tus limites respectivamente para el arreglo de pares e impares.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Cuál pudo haber sido mi error?

Cuales fueron tus errores, en plural.

1. En primer lugar, la inicialización de variables:

   ```
   int A[100],n;
   int B[100], C[100];
   ```

   Cuando una variable no es inicializada, ésta obtiene un valor indeterminado<sup>1</sup>, con tu variable `n` no pasa nada extraño pues cualquiera que sea su valor original lo sobrescribes dos líneas después de su declaración, pero en el caso de las formaciones<sup>2</sup>, los trescientos enteros (`int`) que estás solicitando obtienen un valor indeterminado, para evitar este comportamiento puedes añadir unas llaves vacías a la definición de las formaciones<sup>2</sup> lo cuál provocará que todos sus valores se inicialicen a cero:

   ```
   int A[100]{},n;         // Todos los elementos de 'A' serán 0.
   int B[100]{}, C[100]{}; // Todos los elementos de 'B' y 'C' serán 0.
   ```
2. En segundo lugar, la condición de finalización de tu bucle:

   ```
   for (int i = 0, par = 0, impar = 0; i != 100; ++i)
   //                                  ^^^^^^^^ <-- Hasta que 'i' sea diferente a '100'.
   ```

   Rellenas en `A` valores hasta la `n`-ésima posición pero cuando recorres el bucle para analizar el contenido de `A` lo recorres hasta la centésima posición, esto implica que si `n` es menor a cien, analizarás *100 - `n`* elementos cuyo valor será indeterminado o dicho de otra manera "*números sin sentido y de varios dígitos*"<sup>1</sup>, la corrección evidente es cambiar ese `100` por `n`:

   ```
   for (int i = 0, par = 0, impar = 0; i != n; ++i)
   //                                  ^^^^^^ <-- Hasta que 'i' sea diferente a 'n'.
   ```

Para acabar, una serie de consejos:

- NO uses la cabecera `<conio.h>`, pertenece a las cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c), no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más). Por otro lado dicha cabecera no es estándar, deberías evitarla incluso si programas en [c](/questions/tagged/c) (lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/122350/2742) para saber más).
- Evita abusar de la cláusula `using namespace std`, si la usas hazlo en el ámbito lo más pequeño posible. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber más.
- Cuando sea preciso, favorece el pre-incremento antes que el post-incremento, lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber más.
- Evita abusar de `std::endl`, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/2742) para saber más.
- Si quieres trabajar con colecciones de datos de tamaño indeterminado, evita usar formaciones<sup>2</sup>, mejor usa un contenedor, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/54180/2742) para saber cuál.
- Si quieres operar sobre colecciones de datos, acostúmbrate a usar las herramientas de la cabecera `<algorithm>`.
- Evita las variables cuyo nombre sea una sola letra, el nombre de una variable debe ser auto-explicativo.

Siguiendo los consejos anteriores, tu código [podría parecerse a](https://tio.run/##jZDLctNAEEXXvl8xhILYBFLzfsSOV1nzA8BCyINRlT0y0iibVL7d9EhOYh5FMRupp@/0vX3qw@FDvavS9nh83aR6N2wiWzVtn7tY7dd4ubuPdW6785tqt227Jn8nGZqU2b5q0nyBB8yGvklblqp97A9VHVmfN0tgVkRp2MeuXWJWt0NmqxW7uGu2TY4s7k49tilF3MeU2579GCLLMW26qiiqrovbXXvDLsqEJrH1@nkiZlPEFdms2X21a7vYz6fuorS/tR2bV0Nu2duxy26eVAvMKPUfkYZ0Gj75PRmOj6h@pJnjuENFM9ht@eYmN22an@Zef43bwuT9k9E1bVLKT1/mdZv6zM7iLNgD62IeujSp2Rsml@xxjP6c7OOYp58sp1gva41uU47YL0/lq9tfzZfs6mrsLM42fjdp6e/yc7r8q2Oz/6fnbxufuZ/S/JfraX@@xOPxKKQCh4CEgoaBhYNHgKBLASEhFISGMBAWwkF4iADJIemNBL2WGtJAWkgH6SEDFIcSUDRSQWkoA2WhHJSHCtAcWkBLaHLU0AbaQjtoDx1gOIyAkTAKhgIZGAvjYDxMgOWwAlbCKlgNS3ktrIP1sAGOwwk4CafgNJyBo3UcnIcL8BxewEt4Ba/hDbyFp209fEDgCAJBIigEjWAQLIJDIBiFBuHgxIMTEE5EOCHhxIQTFE5UOGHhpBuxka6AK@QKusKuwCv0Cj5RdKLgo0OMyvkJ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int numero;
    cout << "Digite el numero de elementos que tendra el arreglo: ";
    cin >> numero;

    vector<int> valores(numero);

    for (auto &valor : valores)
    {
        cout << "Digite un numero: ";
        cin >> valor;
    }

    auto pares = partition(valores.begin(), valores.end(), [](const auto &valor) { return valor % 2; });

    cout << "Numeros pares: ";
    for (auto begin = pares; begin != valores.end(); ++begin)
        cout << *begin << '\n';

    cout << "Numeros impares: ";
    for (auto begin = valores.begin(); begin != pares; ++begin)
        cout << *begin << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

---

1. Lo que sea que hubiera en la memoria en el espacio que ocupa.
2. También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Answer (score 1):

*Esto te servirá...*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int A[100],n;
    int B[100], C[100];
    int par = 0, impar = 0;
    cout<<"Digite el numero de elementos que tendra el arreglo: ";
    cin>>n;

    for(int i= 0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"Digite un numero: ";
        cin>>A[i];      
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        if(A[i] % 2 == 0){
           B[par] = A[i];
           par++;
        }else{
           C[impar] = A[i];
           impar++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"NUMEROS PARES " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<par; i++) {
        cout << B[i] << endl;     
    }
    cout<<"NUMEROS IMPARES " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<impar; i++){
        cout << C[i] << endl;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```