# Conversión de decimal a binario con div_t

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda, a la hora de realizar la conversión de un numero dado por el usuario y después de haber pasado el ciclo, no me muestra todos los valores el array y no se en que parte este el error, estoy evaluando div_t para las funciones de quot y rem. Al pedir un dato pido el 29 y sale de resultado 10000000000. Muchas gracias por su ayuda y atención.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int n= 10;
int T[10];  // Arreglo de tamaño de 10 posiciones
int i = 0, cociente, numero;     // Variable para aumentar de posición en el arreglo, gaurdar cociente y variable para guardar numero de usuario
int main(){
    div_t res;                   //res sera del tipo especial div_t
    printf("Introduce el numero a convertir de decimal a binario ");
    scanf("%i", &numero);        // Usuario introduce un valor
    do{                          //inicia funcion
        res = div(numero,2);     //res guardara le division del numero sobre 2
        cociente = res.quot;     //cociente guardara el valor de residuo
        T[i]=res.rem;            //Almacenara el valor de residuo en el vector
        i++;                     //Aumentara el valor del vecto en 1
    }while(cociente !=0 && i<=T[i]);      //mientras cociente sea 0 y i < T, volver a hacer el ciclo.
    for(int i=10;i>0;i--){               //Imprimir los valores del array de manera inversa
        printf("%i", T[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Te falta el `return` de `main`.

Comment: Lo agregue, pero no funciona aun.

Comment: No funciona aún porque esa falta de `return` no era el problema, pero igualmente era algo que estaba mal.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problema

Sólo das una vuelta al bucle de conversión:

```
do{
    res = div(numero,2);
    cociente = res.quot;
    T[i]=res.rem;
    i++;
}while(cociente !=0 && i<=T[i]);
```

Cuando compruebas que `cociente`
no es `0` el resultado es `true`, pero en la primera comprobación verificas que `i` sea menor o igual a `T[i]` en esa primera vuelta `i` ya vale `1` (acabas de hacer `i++`) y `T[i]` **posiblemente** vale `0`, dado que `1` no es menor o igual a `0` el bucle finaliza.

Dije que `T[i]` es posiblemente `0` porque no has inicializado `T`:

```
int T[10];  // Arreglo de tamaño de 10 posiciones
```

Entonces su contenido será aleatorio, si quieres que todas las posiciones sean `0` deberías hacer:

```
int T[10]{};  // Arreglo de tamaño de 10 posiciones
//       ~~ <--- Inicializa T a lista vacío: todo valores 0.
```

Por otro lado, la comprobación `i<=T[i]` es absurda. La formación<sup>1</sup> `T` sólo va a almacenar valores cero o uno (pues es un número binario) mientras que `i` variará de `0` en adelante, cuando `i` valga más de `1` tu bucle finalizará irremediablemente sin haber acabado su tarea.

## Solución

La condición del bucle debe ser que `numero` no sea más divisible, no que el `cociente` no sea `0` y que `T[i]` sea menor o igual a `i`. Así pues divide `numero` entre `2` en cada vuelta y cuando sea `0` habrás acabado.

## Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Tu código parece más [c](/questions/tagged/c) que [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). De hecho puedes etiquetarlo como C++ sólo por haber incluido cabeceras de este lenguaje, las cabeceras  `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` y `<math.h>` son de C, las versiones de C++ son `<cstdio>`, `<cstdlib>` y `<cmath>` y son esas las que deberías usar ([lee este hilo para más información al respecto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48268/librerias-de-c-y-c)), así que has incluido dos veces la misma librería pero en versión C (`<stdlib.h>`) y C++ (`<cstdlib>`) además de haber incluido dos librerías de interacción con la consola de C (`<stdio.h>`) y C++ (`<iostream>`).
- Tanto C como C++ disponen de un operador que permite obtener el [resto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resto) de una división, es el operador `%`. La función [`div`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/div) está pensada para ofrecer el resto de divisiones en coma flotante, ya que el operador de resto sólo funciona con enteros. Dado que estás trabajando con enteros usa ese operador.
- [`printf`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) y [`scanf`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/scanf) son funciones de C incluidas desde la cabecera `<stdio.h>`, dado que has etiquetado la pregunta como C++ deberías estar usando [`std::cin`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) y [`std::cout`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout).
- Un `do`-`while` no es una función.
- En C++ se aconseja que las variables tengan el [ámbito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81mbito_(programaci%C3%B3n)) más pequeño posible, tus variables `n`, `T`, `i`, `cociente` y `numero` tienen ámbito global, deberían ser de ámbito local a `main`.
- La función `main` debe devolver un entero.
- C++ indexa desde `0`, así que la formación<sup>1</sup> `T` tiene índices de `0` a `9`, por lo que tu bucle de impresión debería empezar en `9` y continuar mientras `i` sea mayor o igual a `0`.
- Usa pre incremento/decremento siempre que te sea posible ([lee este artículo para más información al respecto](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/)).

Teniendo cuenta todo lo anterior, tu programa podría quedar así:

```
// Solo necesitas la cabecera iostream
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    /* Las variables son de ambito local
    el residuo lo guardas en T, asi que
    no necesitas una variable para controlarlo. */
    int i{}, numero{}, T[10]{};

    // Usa cout, no uses printf
    std::cout << "Introduce el numero a convertir de decimal a binario\n";
    // Usa cin, no uses scanf
    std::cin >> numero;

    do {                          // Inicia el bucle de conversion
        T[i] = numero % 2;        // Almacena el valor de residuo en el vector
        numero /= 2;              // Divide el numero para el siguiente ciclo
        ++i;                      // Avanza la variable de control (con pre-incremento)
    } while(numero);              // Verifica si ha finalizado el proceso

    // Imprimir la formación de manera inversa,
    // empezando en 9, acabando en 0, usando pre-decremento.
    for (int i = 9; i > 0; --i) {
        // Usa cout, no uses printf
        std::cout << T[i];
    }

    // Es necesario devolver un entero.
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como arreglo, o como array en inglés.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Paula, bueno ya agregue la inicializacion como me indicas pero sigue arrojandome el mismo resultado, segun se el indice del array debe inicializarse en 0 y en la evaluacion del while debe ver si el cociente es diferente de 0 o el array no esta lleno, segun entiendo yo.

Comment: Es que tu algoritmo está mal, tendrás que repensarlo; yo sólo te he indicado por qué el resultado es `10000000000`... que es porque sólo das una vuelta a tu bucle.

Comment: Lo seguiré analizando, gracias