# Copiar una palabra obteniendo memoria dinamica

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando pedir que se ingrese una palabra y luego crear un espacio de memoria nuevo para copiar allí la palabra ingresada por el usuario pero no se como hacerlo.

Tengo esto:

```
#include <string.h> // strlen, strcpy, strcmp, strcat
#include <stdio.h> // sprintf, scanf, ungetc, stdin

int main() {

   char palabra[100];

   printf("Palabra: "); 
   scanf("%s", palabra); // guardamos la palabra en el arreglo

   int tam = strlen(palabra); // me guarda el tamaño de la palabra ingresada

   printf("Escribiste: %s\n", palabra); // muestra la palabra

   printf("Tamaño arreglo: %d\n", tam); // muestra el tamaño

   // creamos memoria dinamica, y "nueva" apunta a la primer celda del arreglo
   char *nueva = new char[tam + 1];

   // creamos un puntero auxiliar para recorrer a "nueva" dejando la posibilidad 
      de acceder al primer caracter luego con el puntero "nueva" que ha quedado 
      intacto.
   char *aux = nueva;

   // creamos un puntero para recorrer el arreglo de la palabra ingresada
   char *p = palabra;

   // mientras el caracter de la celda del arreglo de palabra sea distinto a el 
      final de linea 
   while (*p != '\n') {
    // el contenido a donde apunta aux es modificado por el contenido de a donde 
      apunta p
      *aux = *p;

      aux++; // apuntamos a la siguiente celda del arreglo
      p++;
   }

   printf("Nueva palabra: %s\n", nueva); // mostramos la copia

   delete[] nueva; // liberamos memoria de la copia

   // la memoria del arreglo palabra se libera al finalizar el main() automaticamente

   return 0;
}
```

Pero no funciona asi.

En los comentarios dejo como es mi razonamiento al escribir ese codigo. Y hago comentarios para que me corrigen si digo algo que muestre que estoy equivocado en como entiendo algunas cosas.

Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu código indicas que recorres la formación de caracteres *mientras el carácter de la celda sea distinto a el  final de linea*, pero en ningú lado has añadido el final de línea (`\n`) a la cadena que estás copiando.

Lo puedes arreglar así:

```
// creamos memoria dinamica, y "nueva" apunta a la primer celda del arreglo
char *nueva = new char[tam + 1];
nueva[tam] = '\n';
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Estás etiquetando la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) y es correcto porque utilizas los operadores `new` y `delete` que son exclusivos de C++, pero es lo único que usas de dicho lenguaje en tu código.

Si quieres programar en C++ usando las cabeceras de C, debes usar las versiones adaptadas a C++, en tu caso `<cstring>` y `<cstdio>`, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48268/librerias-de-c-y-c) para saber más al respecto.

---

Sin embargo mi consejo es que, si estás programando en C++, abandones por completo las prácticas y cabeceras de C pasando a usar `std::cin` en lugar de `scanf` y `std::cout` en lugar de `printf`; además de usar `std::string`. Si necesitas practicar con punteros, tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string palabra;

    std::cout << "Palabra: "; 
    // guardamos la palabra en el string, sin limite de tamaño!
    std::getline(std::cin, palabra);

    // me guarda el tamaño de la palabra ingresada    
    const auto tam = palabra.length();

    std::cout << "Escribiste: " << palabra            // muestra la palabra
              << "\nTamaño arreglo: " << tam << '\n'; // muestra el tamaño

    // creamos memoria dinamica, y "nueva" apunta a la primer celda del arreglo
    // añadiendo {} al final, toda la memoria se inicializa a 0
    char *nueva = new char[tam + 1]{};
    nueva[tam] = '\n';

    std::copy(palabra.begin(), palabra.end(), nueva);

    std::cout << "Nueva palabra: " << nueva << '\n'; // mostramos la copia

    delete[] nueva; // liberamos memoria de la copia

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/04lQnZZme4pgPQ5F)</kbd>.

---

El carácter de final de cadena es `0`, cuando imprimes `nueva` al final de la cadena pueden salirte caracteres extraños, esto se debe a que la consola no ha encontrado final de la cadena (`0`) si no que ha encontrado salto de línea (`\n`) y seguirá mostrando caracteres hasta dar con un final de cadena, pertenezca o no a la cadena original.

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta la condición del while. Tenes que cambiar '\n' por '\0'.

```
while (*p != '\0') // '\0' es el fin de cadena
{
    // el contenido a donde apunta aux es modificado por el contenido de a donde apunta p
    *aux = *p;

    aux++; // apuntamos a la siguiente celda del arreglo
    p++;
}
*aux = '\0'; // Finalizar correctamente la palabra nueva con el caracter nulo
```