# Printf me devuelve 0

Tags: c++, c

El archivo termina.txt tiene dos columnas, la primera corresponde a la última terminación de un numero y la segunda al número de veces que ha aparecido un número terminado en la misma.
El objetivo del programa es mostrar la terminación que mas veces ha aparecido y cuantas veces ha aparecido pero al ejecutar los dos valores tanto la terminación como el numero de veces que ha aparecido me dan 0. Ayuda pls.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num[10], veces[10], i, x, y = 0;
    FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("termina.txt", "r");
    if (f1 == NULL) {
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo");
        return -1;
    } else {
        for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            fscanf(f1,"%d %d", &num[i], &veces[i]);
            if (veces[i] > y) {
                veces[i] = y;
                num[i] = x;
            }
        }
        fclose(f1);
        printf("Terminacion que mas veces ha aparecido: %d (%d veces)", x, y);
    }
    /*El archivo de texto termina.txt contiene lo siguiente:
    0 728
    1 732
    2 736
    3 697
    4 738
    5 749
    6 705
    7 732
    8 726
    9 724
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, revisa el [tour] para conocer un poco cómo funciona este sitio y [ask] para entender qué se espera de las preguntas. En este caso la pregunta no tiene contenido. Es solo código. No cuesta nada detallar el problema que tienes y concretarlo. Vale que el título debe ser representativo, pero si no hay contenido que lo respalde sirve de poco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás haciendo la asignación al revés. Esto:

```
if (veces[i]>y){
    veces[i]=y;
    num[i]=x;
    }
```

Debería estar así:

```
if (veces[i]>y){
    y=veces[i];
    x=num[i];
    }
```

En caso contrario lo que haces es sobreescribir `veces` y `num`.

Answer (score 1):

La función `printf` no te devuelve 0, seguramente te devuelve un valor entre 50 y 60. El valor de retorno de `printf` es la cantidad de caracteres que ha escrito, en tu caso escribes una cadena de unos 50 caracteres con dos números entre 1 y 3 dígitos.

Lo que te preocupa no es lo que devuelve `printf` si no lo que escribe; antes de entrar en detalle en cuál es tu fallo voy a señalar unos problemas con tu código:

- La cabecera [`<stdio.h>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) es de [c](/questions/tagged/c) no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Esta cabecera dispone de una versión adaptada a C++ que tiene el prefijo **`c`** y carece de extensión. Si realmente necesitas usar las cabeceras de C (que nunca será el caso) debes usar los equivalentes de C++ [`<cstdio>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio). Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber por qué.
- `printf` y `scanf` son las funciones de lectura de consola de C, en C++ se usan los objetos *stream*: [`std::cout`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) y [`std::cin`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin).
- `FILE`, `fopen`, `fclose` y `fscanf` son las funciones de lectura de archivos de C, en C++ se usan objetos *stream* como [`std::ifstream`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).
- Es buena práctica inicializar tus variables.
- Es buena práctica nombrar a tus variables de manera que el nombre recibido ayude a comprender su objetivo.
- Es buena práctica indentar el código.
- Es buena práctica que las variables tengan el ámbito más pequeño posible.

Teniendo en cuenta los detalles anteriores, y aplicando [la solución propuesta por eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/204713/2742), tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream> // Olvida stdio.h
#include <fstream>

int main() {

// Inicializadores, las variables se crearán con valor 0, las variables tienen
// un nombre claro y autoexplicativo que ayuda a entender su cometido.
//                vv           vv              vvvv                   vvvv
    int numero[10]{}, veces[10]{}, maximo_veces = 0, mayor_terminacion = 0;

// El flujo de archivo ifstream es convertible a booleano, será verdadero
// si el archivo se pudo abrir y falso en caso contrario.
//      vvvvvvvvvvvvv
    if (std::ifstream datos{"termina.txt"})
    {
// No es necesario declarar la variable del bucle fuera del mismo, puede
// limitar su contexto al propio bucle.
//           vvvvvvvvvv
        for (int indice = 0; (indice < 10) && datos; ++indice)
        {
            datos >> numero[indice];
            datos >> veces[indice];

            if (veces[indice] > maximo_veces)
            {
                maximo_veces = veces[indice];
                mayor_terminacion = numero[indice];
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Terminacion que mas veces ha aparecido: " << mayor_terminacion
                  << " (" << maximo_veces << "veces).\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error al abrir el archivo\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ésta es una de las posibles maneras para quedarse con el valor máximo de entre los valores leídos, yo personalmente habría guardado todos los datos en una lista de pares ([`std::pair` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)) y tras la lectura de todos los datos habría buscado el máximo con [`std::max_element` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

```
using elemento = std::pair<int, int>;
using lista_elementos = std::list<elemento>;

lista_elementos valores;

if (std::ifstream datos{"termina.txt"})
{
    for (int indice = 0; (indice < 10) && datos; ++indice)
    {
        elemento e;
        datos >> e.first;
        datos >> e.second;
        valores.push_back(e);
    }

    auto mayor = std::max_element(valores.begin(), valores.end(),
                 [](const elemento &a, const elemento &b) { return a.first < b.frist; });

    std::cout << "Terminacion que mas veces ha aparecido: " << mayor->first
              << " (" << mayor->second << "veces).\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Error al abrir el archivo\n";
}
```