# No puedo sumar una variable en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy en proceso de realizar un programa donde cuente con preguntas y 4 alternativas y al final si están correctas te entrega el resultado, no conozco mucho sobre C++ es un trabajo para la Universidad, no logro que al final se sumen las variables, al iniciar y colocar las respuestas correctas me da como resultado = 0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int p1, p2, n1, n2, resultado;
    printf("esta es tu evaluación cuenta con 10 preguntas de selección multiple \n");
    printf("pregunta1 \n");
    printf("¿Cuantos ojos tiene un perro? \n");
    printf("1) 2 ojos \n");
    printf("2) 9 ojos \n");
    printf("3) 2 ojos \n");
    printf("4) 7 ojo \n");
    printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
    scanf("%i", &p1);
    if (p1 == 1) {
        n1 = 1;
    }
    else {
    }
    n1 = 0;
    printf("cuantas patas tiene un perro \n");
    printf("1) 3 patas \n");
    printf("2) 7 patas \n");
    printf("3) 4 patas \n");
    printf("4) 9 patas \n");
    printf("Indica tu respuesta \n");
    scanf("%i", &p2);
    if (p2 == 3) {
        n2 = 1;
    }
    else {
    }
    n2 = 0;
    resultado = n1 + n2;
    printf("tu resultado del examen es de %i", resultado);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Al iniciar y colocar las respuestas correctas me da como resultado = 0

Normal, respondas lo que respondas, igualas el resultado a cero:

```
…

if (p1 == 1) {
    n1 = 1; // <---- Guardas 1
}
else {
}
n1 = 0;     // <---- Sobrescribes con 0

…

if (p2 == 3) {
    n2 = 1; // <---- Guardas 1
}
else {
}
n2 = 0;     // <---- Sobrescribes con 0
```

Seguramente querías poner la sobrescritura en el `else`:

```
…

if (p1 == 1) {
    n1 = 1;
}
else {
    n1 = 0;
}

…

if (p2 == 3) {
    n2 = 1;
}
else {
    n2 = 0;
}
```

Puedes incluso simplificar con un operador ternario:

```
…

n1 = (p1 == 1) ? 1 : 0;

…

n2 = (p2 == 3) ? 1 : 0;
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Además del problema mencionado, tu código tiene otros problemas que vale la pena mencionar:

- En C++ la entrada desde consola en C++ es mediante `std::cin` y la salida mediante `std::cout`. Las funciones `printf` y `scanf` pertenecen a las utilidades de C.
- Estás incluyendo cabeceras que **NO usas**. Pero además las cabeceras `<stdio.h>`, `<math.h>` y `<stdlib.h>` son de [c](/questions/tagged/c) no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Las cabeceras de C disponen de una versión adaptada a C++ que tiene el prefijo `c` y carecen de extensión. Si realmente necesitas usar las cabeceras de C (que rara vez será el caso y ciertamente no es el tuyo) debes usar los equivalentes de C++  ,   y  . Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber por qué.
- Relacionado con el punto anterior: estás incluyendo a la vez `<stdlib.h>` y `<cstdlib>` y ambas cabeceras son la misma pero en versión C y C++ respectivamente.
- La cabecera `<conio.h>` no forma parte de las [cabeceras estándar de C](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/header). Esta cabecera es una utilidad proveída por el compilador de la plataforma, declara varias funciones para permitir al usuario interactuar con la consola y las funciones proveídas varían entre compiladores y plataformas, en definitiva no sigue ni el [ANSI C](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) ni el [POSIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). Ese es el motivo por el que no se recomienda su uso, pues hace que el código no sea [portable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portabilidad).

#### Propuesta.

Tu código podría ser más C++ si usas programación orientada a objetos y las utilidades de C++:

```
struct Pregunta
{
    std::string texto;
    unsigned correcta;
};

Pregunta preguntas[] =
{
    { "¿Cuantos ojos tiene un perro?\n1) 2 ojos\n2) 9 ojos\n3) 2 ojos\n4) 7 ojos", 1 },
    { "¿Cuantas patas tiene un perro?\n1) 3 patas\n2) 7 patas\n3) 4 patas\n4) 9 patas", 3 }
};

int main()
{
    int aciertos = 0;
    std::cout << "Esta es tu evaluación cuenta con 10 preguntas de selección multiple\n";

    for (const auto &pregunta : preguntas)
    {
        std::cout << pregunta.texto;

        int respuesta;
        std::cin >> respuesta;

        aciertos += static_cast<int>(respuesta == pregunta.correcta);
    }

    std::cout << "Tu resultado del examen es de " << aciertos;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: De hecho podría simplificarse aún más: `n1 = (p1 == 1);`

Comment: No exactamente. En [tag:c] el estándar indica que el resultado de una expresión booleana será `0` para falso y `1` para verdadero. En [tag:c++] el resultado es `false` para falso y `true` para verdadero. Mientras que `false` será siempre `0`, `true` puede ser cualquier valor.

Comment: No exactamente. Una cosa es la conversión `int->bool`, la cual es como dices, y otra cosa es `bool->int`. En este caso `false->0` y `true->1`

Comment: Perdón, tienes razón, he encontrado la cita relevante en [el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf): **7.6.6** *A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one*.