# ¿ Como eliminar avisos old-style-cast (C casts) al usar cabeceras de C en código C++?

Tags: c++, gcc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto C++ (usando g++), en el que estamos usando librerías externas en C.

Por este motivo, el compilador emite multitud de *warnings*:

> *warning*: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]

El problema es sencillo: los archivos de cabecera del código C usan el *casting* propio del lenguaje: `(void *)myVar( NULL );`

Como he dicho, son de una librería externa y no quiero tocarlos, so pena de tener que realizar un muy gran trabajo manual, y repetirlo cada vez que actualicemos la versión de la librería.

¿ Hay alguna forma de eliminar esos *warnings* **solo para uno o varios archivos de cabecera** ?

Comment: ¿Qué sucede si encierras las cabeceras de [tag:C] en cláusulas `extern "C" { #include "cosa" }`?

Comment: ¡ Anda carajo ! ¡ Funciona ! Pues no se me había ocurrido :-O ¿ Te importaría escribir una respuesta ?

Answer (score 7):

Después de unas cuantas búsquedas, encontré la solución:

> [g++ warning on old-style-cast (C casts) with a legacy C header having macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54595637/8663418)

Usando `g++`, podemos usar **`#pragma`**:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wold-style-cast"
#include "archivo_cabecera_c.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

El código anterior:

1. **Guarda** el estado actual de la generación de avisos.
2. Deshabilita los avisos `old-style cast` (convirtiendose en el estado actual).
3. Incluye el archivo de cabecera problemático.
4. **Restaura** el estado previo: vuelve a activar la generación de avisos.

No estamos limitados a 1 solo `#include`, sino que podemos colocar varios.

Es necesario colocar el código anterior **en todos los archivos `.cpp` que usen las cabeceras problemáticas**.

Como uso adicional, no estamos limitados solo a esos *warnings*:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wold-style-cast"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
#include "archivo_cabecera_c.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Ahí, además de lo anterior, eliminamos los avisos sobre variables sin usar.

Answer (score 7):

> ¿ Hay alguna forma de eliminar esos *warnings* **solo para uno o varios archivos de cabecera** ?

«Al César lo que es del César y a Dios lo que es de Dios».

— Jesús de Nazaret — Mateo 22:20.

---

C++ y C son lenguajes distintos con convenciones distintas, normas distintas, estándares distintos e incluso distintas palabras clave. Son dos mundos que no deberían mezclarse (por eso, si se necesita una cabecera de C en C++ [se debe usar la versión adaptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48305/2742)).

Usar convenciones de C en C++ provoca en muchos casos una alarma **y así debe ser**. Eliminar dicha alarma puede ser contraproducente y propenso a errores, esas alarmas están ahí por un buen motivo ¿Qué pasa si eliminas esa alarma (y te olvidas de reactivarla) y alguien usa esas conversiones? ¡Pues que esa injuria pasará desapercibida!

Por suerte (o por desgracia) C y C++ están estrechamente relacionados y muchas veces se considera necesario usar librearías de C en C++ (al revés es casi imposible), por eso se permite marcar bloques de código como si perteneciesen a C:

```
extern "C"
{
#include "Cabecera_de_c.h"
}
```

Todo el código incluido en el bloque `extern "C"` será tratado como C con sus convenciones, normas y palabras clave. Puedes dejar las alarmas activadas.

Esta herramienta, añade además una clara semántica al bloque: *Eso pertenece a otro lenguaje*, lo cuál puede ser de utilidad para otros programadores que examinen el código.