# Si no tiene resultado real, se muestra mensaje de error C++

Tags: c++, números-enteros

El problema es este.

Se ingresan los valores de a y c, y se obtienen los resultados 
de la formula general. si el resultado no es real, se muestra 
mensaje de error, mi programa fue este.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
    float A, B, C, F1, F2;
    int main ()
{

cout << "Ingrese A: ";
  cin >> A;
  cout << "Ingrese B: ";
  cin >> B;
  cout << "Ingrese C: ";
  cin >> C;

  F1=(-B + sqrt((B*B)-(4*A*C)))/(2*A);
  F2=(-B - sqrt((B*B)-(4*A*C)))/(2*A);

  cout<< "El valor de F1 es: " << F1;
  cout<< "\nEl valor de F2 es: " << F2;

 return 0;
}
```

si el resultado no es real, dirá un mensaje con `nan`, pero yo requiero 
mandar un mensaje que diga error.

Ya trate declarando `nan` pero aun así no lo reconoce y sigue mandando
el mismo error de `nan`.

Comment: ¿no es suficiente una condicional de acuerdo al valor del discriminante?

Comment: Me parece que te falta evaluar el resultado para mostrar lo que desees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En matemáticas, las soluciones de una ecuación general de segundo grado de la forma      `a*x^2 + b*x + c = 0` se obtienen de la fórmula general obtenida por Bhaskara: `x_1,2 = (-b +- sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/(2*a)`, siendo el argumento de la raíz cuadrada el llamado **discriminante**.

El valor que tome el discriminante, generalmente denotado con la letra griega delta mayúscula (**Δ**), determina qué tipo de raíces tendrá la ecuación:

*Si Δ>0: las raíces serán reales y distintas.

*Si Δ=0: las raíces serán reales e iguales.

*Si Δ<0 las raíces serán complejas y conjugadas.

En tu caso, basta con corroborar si Δ<0. Si es así, entonces imprimimos el mensaje de error; de lo contrario, mostramos el cálculo completo.

Esto lo podemos lograr de la forma:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    float A,B,C,F1,F2,discriminante;

    std::cout << "Ingrese A: ";
    std::cin >> A;

    std::cout << "Ingrese B: ";
    std::cin >> B;

    std::cout << "Ingrese C: ";
    std::cin >> C;

    discriminante = pow(B,2) - 4*A*C;

    if(discriminante<0) std::cout << "ERROR";
    else
    {
        F1 = (-B + sqrt(discriminante))/(2*A);
        F2 = (-B - sqrt(discriminante))/(2*A);

        std::cout << "El valor de F1 es: " << F1 << std::endl
                  << "El valor de F2 es: " << F2;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

¡Espero haber sido de ayuda! Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Akamai tu respuesta me ayudo con mis dudas del programa! Saludos amigo.

Answer (score 4):

Si estás programando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no deberías usar cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c) si no la versión adaptada a C++. Así que debes substituir la cabecera `<math.h>` (de C) por la cabecera `<cmath>`. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más del tema.

Usando la cabecera correcta, puedes hacer uso del objeto [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) en la cabecera homónima ([`<complex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/complex)); este objeto almacena [números complejos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_complejo) y ofrece todas las funciones para trabajar con ellos.

Por lo tanto, si usas números complejos en tu código:

```
float A, B, C;
cout << "Ingrese A: ";
cin >> A;
cout << "Ingrese B: ";
cin >> B;
cout << "Ingrese C: ";
cin >> C;

auto F1=(-B + sqrt( complex((B*B)-(4*A*C))) )/(2*A);
//                  ^^^^^^^ <--- Número complejo
auto F2=(-B - sqrt( complex((B*B)-(4*A*C))) )/(2*A);
//                  ^^^^^^^ <--- Número complejo

cout<< "El valor de F1 es: " << F1;
cout<< "\nEl valor de F2 es: " << F2;
```

No obtendrás nunca `nan` como resultado. Para *x<sup>2</sup> - 2x -8* las dos soluciones son -2 y 4 y obtienes la siguiente salida:

> ```
> El valor de F1 es: (4,0)
> El valor de F2 es: (-2,-0)
> ```

Para *2x<sup>2</sup> – 2x + 5* las dos soluciones son imaginarias y obtienes la siguiente salida:

> ```
> El valor de F1 es: (0.5,1.5)
> El valor de F2 es: (0.5,-1.5)
> ```

Por lo tanto, para comprobar si el resultado es real, tan sólo debes verificar que no tenga parte imaginaria:

```
void mostrar(const std::complex<float> &resultado)
{
    if (resultado.imag() != .0f)
        std::cout << "Error, no es un numero real";
    else
        std::cout << resultado.real();
}
```

Puedes ver el código completo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJda8IwFH1ufsWZg5FM67RsL1YLVhzsZ4SYdh1p4pJUhLG/vi5Vp1NksIcLl8s55577IdbruBSibW8rLVSzkphWxnkreZ2RU03U3L@eFUy9VnKbEbIx1Qp1x@GWCqOdh/OryeSAmBbKcJ/hzkrXKM9XhpEPElUF6LEyrGpeUoabGYajgpEoOig0HtMpektrjR1AG0iHRkM3tbQGwaTqpSSSyslLzkm7Q1GWkk9CKu1R80qD7jw0rtIlNK@lW3MhO9spIdHOMOYD5AMsgvzRxosug6zEfIKurQhCWYb5NUh@BsmvQRZnkEXXeb893niD/fbeDGaHdEtpjnvkDDHoY8jmIRaMpWe05zFmNM7Rh3u3np5kGMMDaNLxLinJnhL/Tfk1wVJhw5WxCI8QGkq3n@TnB57HLP0HOtmJW@kbqzEKd2rbhMQJeSJfolC8dG0cDjMT/X7CvwE)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas incluir un condicional para validar el valor del discriminante, es decir la expresión afectada por la raíz cuadrada, si este es menor de cero, mandar un mensaje de que las raíces no son reales y terminar el programa, y si este es mayor o igual a cero continuar con las demás operaciones, algo así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>//*

using namespace std;
float A, B, C, F1, F2;
int main()
{

    cout << "Ingrese A: ";
    cin >> A;
    cout << "Ingrese B: ";
    cin >> B;
    cout << "Ingrese C: ";
    cin >> C;

    //guardando la discriminante en F2 (momentaneamente)
    F2 = (B*B) - (4 * A*C);
    //validando el valor de F2
    if (F2 < 0) {
        cout << "Las raicez no son reales" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    F1 = (-B + sqrt(F2)) / (2 * A);
    F2 = (-B - sqrt(F2)) / (2 * A);

    cout << "El valor de F1 es: " << F1;
    cout << "\nEl valor de F2 es: " << F2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias 4lrdyD me a ayudado mucho! saludo.