# ¿cómo imprimir las cadenas que contiene un arreglo de punteros?

Tags: c++, string, punteros, punteros-inteligentes

Estoy intentando hacer un código que saca los valores de una cadena de caracteres y los quiero guardar en un array de cadenas, entonces lo que hice fue definir un arreglo de punteros para guardar los diferentes valores allí, pero al hacerlo e imprimir siempre imprime el último dato. No sé si estoy leyendo mal el contenido que hay en los punteros o que puedo hacer, muchas gracias
El código es:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int cont=0, cont2=0, cont3=0, len=0, band=0;
    char cadena_num[20];
    char *vector_ref_tol[5];
    char datos2[]="{\"estado\":\"200 ok\",\"carnet\":\"2151022\",\"velocidad\":1719,\"frecuencia\":55.34,\"voltaje\":216.28,\"temperatura\":35.53,\"tiempo_init_op\":1621055844824}";
    printf("%s\n", datos2);
    len=strlen(datos2);
    for(cont=0; cont<len; cont++)
          {
              if(datos2[cont]==':' )
              {
                    cont3=cont+1;
                    band++;
              while(datos2[cont3]!=',' && datos2[cont3]!='}' && band>2)
                  {
                    cadena_num[cont2]=datos2[cont3];
                    cont2++;
                    cont3++;
                  }
                  cont2=0;
                  if(band>2 && band<=7)
                  {
                     
                      vector_ref_tol[band-3]=cadena_num;
                      printf("%s \n", vector_ref_tol[band-3]);
                  }
                  
                  cont=cont3;
  
              }
  
          }
    for(cont=0; cont<5; cont++)
    
    {
        printf("%s",vector_ref_tol[cont] );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código es un galimatías ininteligible mal sangrado, con una pésima elección de nombres de variables y en el lenguaje equivocado. No me extraña que tengas dificultades para obtener el comportamiento que esperas pues es tremendamente difícil entender lo que haces.

Dado que has etiquetado la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), has tomado decisiones incorrectas en:

- **Cabeceras**: Las cabeceras `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>` y `<stdlib.h>` son de [c](/questions/tagged/c) y no deben usarse en C++, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48305/2742) para saber más del tema.
- **Definición de `main`**: En C++ las funciones que no reciben parámetros, se definen con una lista de argumentos vacía, no con una lista con `void` como único parámetro.
- **Manejo del texto**: En C++ el texto se maneja con el objeto `std::string` no con formaciones de caracteres.
- **Comunicación con la consola**: En C++ se usan los objetos de flujo de datos `std::cin` y `std::cout` para leer y escribir en la consola, las herramientas `printf` y `scanf` son de C.

Usando las herramientas adecuadas, tu código puede reducirse a esto:

```
std::string datos = "{\"estado\":\"200 ok\",\"carnet\":\"2151022\",\"velocidad\":1719,\"frecuencia\":55.34,\"voltaje\":216.28,\"temperatura\":35.53,\"tiempo_init_op\":1621055844824}";

for (auto inicio = datos.find(':'), fin = datos.find_first_of(",}", inicio);
    inicio != std::string::npos;
    inicio = datos.find(':', fin), fin = datos.find_first_of(",}", inicio))
{
    std::cout << "Dato: " << datos.substr(inicio + 1, fin - inicio - 1) << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBboMwEETP@Cu27gFQCcIE0hSSnPoZSJFrTOSW2MiYXiK@nS4hVVuplXpbPc/OrEd03Uq0XJ@m6V5p0Q61hJ0yvbOSnw/ki/W/IGeVPh0IUdrBmSsdhORCvN7VRbG8Qc2d6WEP9FJR2Ttem4oWFU2TBMxbRaOKCm61dAtlOUvS9IrfZWuEqnmNL@yRPSFqrBSD1EJxZHker7NZZ1rHXyWSlG3idIvIyXMnLXeDnYXrPM7XM1WIzVFp5Y6mm103KUvyfJtl2zQbaUmI1xgLAR@cAZQJZfDw6wfiRuk68As/jADHH/jYKNujZRPQaKTRbTMsPy3u9vCtkKLQnelL4nl/JFwD/h8TEg8bXyoXZnCw2wF9xq0C6DwvBv3wgvHBLfIB2OK/@rxxBSyc1X6lfbxtxCqsxP40JCUZp@kD)</kbd>.