# ¿Como guardar literalmente un string en una lista doblemente enlazada?

Tags: c++

Tengo un archivo grupo.dat similar a lo siguiente

| i | Correo | Apellido | Nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a@.mx | a------- | a----- |
| 1 | b@.mx | b------- | b----- |
| 2 | c@.mx | c------- | c----- |

Donde extraigo cada linea y la guardo en un arreglo de strings

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define path "grupo.dat"

using namespace std;

typedef struct key_value
{
    char index[50];
    char mail[50];
    char firstname[50];
    char lastname1[50];
    char lastname2[50];
} student;

struct node {
    string data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    int size;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    if(!file) exit(1);

    char buffer[114];
    int row_count = 0;
    int field_count = 0;

    student students[58];
    string toostudents[28];
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file))
    {
        field_count = 0;
        row_count++;
        if(row_count == 1) continue;

        char *field = strtok(buffer, "|");
        while(field)
        {
            if(field_count == 0) strcpy(students[i].index, field);
            if(field_count == 1) strcpy(students[i].mail, field);
            if(field_count == 2) strcpy(students[i].lastname1, field);
            if(field_count == 3) strcpy(students[i].lastname2, field);
            if(field_count == 4) strcpy(students[i].firstname, field);

            field = strtok(NULL, "|");
            field_count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 3; i < 58; i++)
    {
        if(i > 2 && i%2!=0)
        {
            if(j > 28) break;
            toostudents[j] = string(students[i].lastname1) + students[i].lastname2 + students[i].firstname;
            j++;
        }
    }

    string aux = toostudents[0];
    cout << aux << endl;
    struct node* list = NULL;
    list->prev = NULL;
    list->data = aux;
    list->next = NULL;
    list->size = 1;

    cout << "Data: " << list->data << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Yo me lo imagino como `<-[prev, data, next]->`, donde para cada data, le pertenece un reglon asociado. Pero al momento de correr mi programa me da un error, alguien que me pueda ayudar a solucionarlo o optimizar lo que ya tengo hecho. Por su ayuda gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Seguro que vas a recibir buenas respuestas, es una buena pregunta. Sin embargo, te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta y añadir el texto completo del error que te da, no resumas el error. Eso ayuda a depurar más rápido tu código :) Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

He ejecutado tu programa y da un error de memoria, es difícil saber dónde está el error sin depurar pero no pienso hacerlo, ese error es derivado del mal diseño de tu código, el cual es mucho más complicado de lo necesario:

1. Estás mezclando cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c) con cabeceras de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Las cabeceras `<stdlib.h>` y `<string.h>` son de C y no deben usarse en C++. Lee [esta publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48305/2742) para saber más del tema.

   1. Incluyes cabeceras de diferentes lenguajes que tienen el mismo cometido: la cabecera `<iostream>` de C++ da acceso a los objetos de lectura y escritura de la consola, la cabecera `<fstream>` de C++ da acceso a los objetos de lectura y escritora de archivos y la cabecera `<stdlib.h>` de C da acceso a funciones estándar del lenguaje que incluyen lectura y escritura de la consola y de archivos.
2. En C++ la entrada y salida de consola y archivos se hace mediante objetos de flujo de datos que están definidos en las cabeceras `<iostream>` y `<fstream>` respectivamente, deberías usar esos flujos de datos en lugar de `FILE`.
3. En C++ las cadenas de caracteres se tratan con el objeto `std::string` que está incluido en la cabecera `<string>` (que no incluyes), la cabecera `<string.h>` (que sí incluyes) se usa en C para tratar formaciones de caracteres.

Eso sólo respecto las primeras cuatro líneas de tu código, del resto:

1. En C++ las estructuras son tipos básicos, no necesitas definir un tipo (*`type` `def` inition*) para definir una:

   ```
   struct student // sin typedef
   {
       char index[50];
       char mail[50];
       char firstname[50];
       char lastname1[50];
       char lastname2[50];
   };
   ```

   Ni necesitas anteponer `struct` para instanciar una:

   ```
   struct node {
       string data;
       node *next; // sin struct
       node *prev; // sin struct
       int size;
   };
   ```
2. En C++ las cadenas de caracteres se manejan con el objeto `std::string`, no con formaciones de caracteres:

   ```
   struct student
   {
       // Todo objetos std::string
       std::string index;
       std::string mail;
       std::string firstname;
       std::string lastname1;
       std::string lastname2;
   };
   ```
3. En C++ los archivos se leen con un objeto de flujo de entrada desde archivo (`std::ifstream` `i`nput `f`ile `stream`) que abre el archivo automáticamente al construirse y lo cierra al destruirse además de ser convertible a `bool` tomando un valor `false` si hubieron fallos al abrir el archivo:

   ```
   if (ifstream file{path})
   {
       // leer datos
   }
   else
   {
      // fallo al abrir
   }
   ```
4. Puedes leer líneas de un archivo de texto con `std::getline`, sin necesidad de un búfer intermedio:

   ```
   if (ifstream file{path})
   {
       // Se ejecuta por cada linea de 'file' mientras haya lineas que leer
       for (std::string linea; std::getline(file, linea); )
       {
           // Procesar linea leida
       }   
   }
   else
   {
      // fallo al abrir
   }
   ```
5. En C++ se suelen usar contenedores de datos (como `std::list` o `std::vector`) para almacenar información, a estos contenedores de datos se les puede preguntar la cantidad de elementos o modificar su tamaño dinámicamente.

   ```
   std::list<student> students;
   std::vector<std::string> toostudents;
   ```
6. En C++ la lectura/escritura de datos de/a archivo o consola se suele hacer sobrecargando los operadores de inyección (`>>`) o extracción (`<<`) de flujo de datos:

   ```
   std::ifstream &operator>>(std::ifstream &i, student &s)
   {
       std::string line;
       std::getline(i, line);
       auto campos = split(line);
       s.index = campos[0];
       s.mail = campos[1];
       s.firstname = campos[2];
       s.lastname1 = campos[3];
   }
   ```