# ¿Por qué mi matriz sólo imprime los últimos valores que le paso?

Tags: c++, array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int N,A;
    int Calificaciones [N][A];
    int cont5,cont4,cont3,cont2,cont;
    int notas[cont3];   

    cout << "Ingrese numero de alumnos."<<endl;
    cin>>A;
    cout<< "Ingrese numero de notas por cada alumno"<<endl;
    cin>>N;

    for(cont = 0; cont <N;cont++){      
        cout<< endl;        
        for(cont2 = 0;cont2<A;cont2++){     
            cout<<"Alumno " <<cont2<<" Nota "<<cont<<":"<<endl;
            cin>> Calificaciones[cont][cont2];              
        }           
        cout<<"-------------------------------"<<endl;
    }

    for(cont=0;cont<N;cont++){
        for(cont2=0;cont2<A;cont2++){           
            printf("%5.2d ", Calificaciones[cont][cont2] );                 
        }
        cout<<endl; 
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la inicialización de la matriz, ya que las variables `N` y `A` no está inicializadas y el compilador no sabe las dimensiones reales de la matriz. Puedes realizar la creación matriz después quee leas `N` y `A`, es decir poner `int Calificaciones [N][A];` después de leer `N`.

```
...    
int N,A;    
int cont5,cont4,cont3,cont2,cont;
int notas[cont3];   

cout << "Ingrese numero de alumnos."<<endl;
cin>>A;
cout<< "Ingrese numero de notas por cada alumno"<<endl;
cin>>N;
int Calificaciones [N][A];
...
```

Comment: Tu respuesta me fue de mucha ayuda !!!

Comment: En C++ los tamaños de las matrices deben ser conocidos en tiempo de compilación, si se usan valores de tiempo de ejecución entonces hablamos de un [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) que no es estándar y por tanto podría dejar de funcionar en otros compiladores o en otras versiones del mismo compilador.

Answer (score 2):

La solución propuesta por danielpmsv seguramente te vaya a funcionar si utilizas un compilador como g++. Esto es debido a que dicho compilador soporta lo que se conoce como "*arrays de longitud variable*" (VLA, en inglés), lo cual es propio del lenguaje C. Sin embargo, este tipo de arrays no han sido adoptados en el estandar de C++, y como ya indique, algunos compiladores lo soportan, como una extensión. Por ejemplo, si intentas usar el compilador del Visual Studio, éste te marcará un error.

La razón es sencilla, en C++ los arreglos tienen que tener un tamaño estático que sea conocido en tiempo de compilación y no de ejecución. Vale decir, que al momento de declarar un arreglo, tienes que indicar cual es su tamaño:

```
int arre[n]
//       ~~~~~~~~ <--- ERROR. El tamaño del arreglo es una variable.

int arre[10]
//       ~~~~~~~~ <--- CORRECTO. En este caso el tamaño del arreglo es una constante: 10.
```

Del mismo modo sucede con los arreglos bidimensionales (también conocidos como matrices). Es por eso que las declaraciones `int Calificaciones [N][A];` y `int notas[cont3];` son incorrectas debido a que tanto `N`, `A` y `cont3` son todas variables y no expresiones constantes.

Y pues bien, entonces como soluciono todo esto?

Hay dos maneras: la antigua (al estilo C) que consiste en usar punteros y los operadores `new` y `delete`, o al estilo C++, la cual se basa en hacer uso del contenedor `vector`, el cual esta definido en la librería `<vector>`, que es justamente la última cabecera que has incluido en tu programa.

Debido a eso, voy a proponer la solución más "moderna" (entre comillas, porque la librería `<vector>` existía ya desde el estandar de 1998).

Para empezar, la declaración es distinta:

```
    vector<T> nombreVector(tam)
    //     ~~~~~~~~ <--- Aquí T representa el tipo de variable que quieres almacenar en el vector.
//                       Puede ser un tipo primitivo como int o un tipo definido a partir de un Struct/Class creada por el programador.
```

En tu ejercicio, en lugar de `int notas[cont3]`, con `vector` lo haríamos de la siguiente manera: `vector<int> notas(cont3)`. Para la matriz `int Calificaciones [N][A]`, tendríamos:

```
vector<vector<int>> calificaciones(N, vector<int>(A))
```

Volviendo a tu ejercicio, noto que el arreglo `notas` nunca es utilizado en tu programa. Tampoco haces uso de la cabecera `<math.h>`. Por otro lado, creas de manera innecesaria contadores. Es mejor crearlos a la hora utilizarlos en el bucle `for`. Y por último, evita mezclar `cout/cin` con `printf/scanf`.

Con las correcciones indicadas tu programa debería quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int N, A;

    cout << "Ingrese numero de alumnos: ";
    cin >> A;
    cout << "Ingrese numero de notas por cada alumno: ";
    cin >> N;

    vector<vector<int>> calificaciones(N, vector<int>(A));

    for (int cont = 0; cont < N; cont++) 
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (int cont1 = 0; cont1 < A; cont1++) 
        {
            cout << "Alumno " << cont1 + 1 << " Nota " << cont + 1 << ": " << endl;
            cin >> calificaciones[cont][cont1];
        }
        cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
    }

    for (int cont = 0; cont < N; cont++) 
    {
        for (int cont1 = 0; cont1 < A; cont1++) 
        {
            cout << calificaciones[cont][cont1] << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Otras cosas a tener en cuenta:**

1. Evita el `using namespace std;`. Revisa este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/63114).
2. Trata de no "abusar" del `std::endl`. Aquí el [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/8781554) correspondiente (en inglés).
3. Evita utilizar el `system("pause")`. Para una explicación ojea este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1107705/8781554) (también en inglés).

Comment: Gracias por la explicacion. Se que habian variables sin utilizar en mi desesperacion me olvide de borrarlar antes de formular mi pregunta. Gracias!