# Matriz dinamica error

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando implementar un operator* para multiplicar dos matrices pero no me lo hace correctamente y no se porque, este es el código que he intentado:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class matriz {
public:
    matriz() {};
    ~matriz();
    matriz(const matriz& m);
    void pedirDatos();
    void mostrarMatriz(double **puntero_matriz, int filas, int columnas);
    double& operator()(int fila, int columna);
    int getFilas() { return m_filas; };
    int getColumnas() { return m_columnas; };
    double**getPuntero_matriz() { return m_puntero_matriz; };
    matriz operator*(const matriz& m);

private:
    double **m_puntero_matriz;
    int m_filas;
    int m_columnas;

};
matriz::~matriz() {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_filas; ++i)
        delete[] m_puntero_matriz[i];
    delete[] m_puntero_matriz;
}
void matriz::pedirDatos() {
    cout << "Digite numero de filas: ";
    cin >> m_filas;
    cout << "Digite numero de columnas: ";
    cin >> m_columnas;

    m_puntero_matriz = new double *[m_filas]; //reservamos memoria para filas
    for (int i = 0; i < m_filas; i++) {
        m_puntero_matriz[i] = new double[m_columnas]; //reservamos memoria para columnas
    }

    cout << "\nDigitando elementos de la matriz: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < m_filas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_columnas; j++) {
            cout << "Digite un numero[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> *(*(m_puntero_matriz + i) + j);
        }
    }
}

void matriz::mostrarMatriz(double **puntero_matriz, int filas, int columnas) {
    cout << "\n\nImprimiendo matriz:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
            cout << puntero_matriz[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}



matriz::matriz(const matriz& m) {
    m_filas = m.m_filas;
    m_columnas = m.m_columnas;
    m_puntero_matriz = new double*[m_filas]; //reservamos memoria para filas

    for (int i = 0; i < m_filas; i++) { //reservamos memoria para columnas
        m_puntero_matriz[i] = new double[m_columnas];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m_filas; i++) { //asignamos valores a la matrix
        for (int j = 0; j < m_columnas; j++) {
            m_puntero_matriz[i][j] = m.m_puntero_matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
}

matriz matriz::operator*(const matriz& m) {
    matriz mat = m;
    float sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->m_filas - 1; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < m.m_columnas - 1; ++j){
            sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < m.m_filas - 1; ++k){
                sum += this->m_puntero_matriz[i][k] * m.m_puntero_matriz[k][j];
            }

            mat.m_puntero_matriz[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

matriz& matriz::operator=(const matriz& m) {
    if (this != &m){
        for (int i = 0; i < m_filas; i++){
            if (m_puntero_matriz[i] != nullptr){
                delete[] m_puntero_matriz;
            }
        }
        if (m_puntero_matriz != nullptr){
            delete[] m_puntero_matriz;
        }
        m_columnas = m.m_columnas;
        m_filas = m.m_filas;
        m_puntero_matriz = new double *[m_filas];
        for (int i = 0; i < m_filas; i++){
            m_puntero_matriz[i] = new double[m_columnas];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m_filas; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < m_columnas; j++){
                m_puntero_matriz[i][j] = m.m_puntero_matriz[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

int main(){

    matriz mat1;
    matriz mat2;
    matriz resultado;

    mat1.pedirDatos();
    mat1.mostrarMatriz(mat1.getPuntero_matriz(), mat1.getFilas(), mat1.getColumnas());

    mat2.pedirDatos();
    mat2.mostrarMatriz(mat2.getPuntero_matriz(), mat2.getFilas(), mat2.getColumnas());

    resultado = mat1 * mat2;

    resultado.mostrarMatriz(resultado.getPuntero_matriz(), resultado.getFilas(), resultado.getColumnas());


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Por ejemplo, dadas las matrices `m1` de 2 filas y 1 columna, y `m2` de una fila y dos columnas:

```
m1 = {{2},
      {-1}}
m2 = {{3,5}}
```

Obtengo un resultado de `res = {0, 5}` cuando debería ser una matriz 2 filas y 2 columnas con el siguiente contenido:

```
{{ 6,10},
 {-3,-5}}
```

Comment: "*no me lo hace correctamente y no se porque*" ¿qué es lo que recibes y qué es lo que esperabas recibir?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus La multiplicación no la ejecuta correctamente, al final del post pongo lo que debería dar, el resultado de multiplicar dos matrices.

Comment: Además de que no pones qué esperas recibir (sólo lo que recibes), tu resultado no tiene sentido: Multiplicar una matriz de 1×2 por una de 2×1 debería resultar en una matriz de 2×2.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus he añadido el resultado que debería dar. Claro que no tiene sentido, por eso hago la pregunta.

Comment: Es imposible que al multiplicar dos matrices con números positivos te de como resultado filas con números negativos.

Comment: ups cierto, edito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes una serie de problemas en tu código:

- Problemas de cabeceras y estilo:

  - La cabecera [`<stdlib.h>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header) es de [c](/questions/tagged/c) no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Esta cabecera disponen de una versión adaptada a C++ que tiene el prefijo **`c`** y carece de extensión. Si realmente necesitas usar las cabeceras de C (que nunca será el caso) debes usar el equivalente de C++ [`<cstdlib>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib). Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber por qué. Pero en tu caso ni siquiera estás utilizando las utilidaes que aporta esa librería; así que ni la incluyas.
  - No hay obligación de usar la cláusula `using namespace std;` pues es sólo es una ayuda a la escritura de código; si decides usar esta cláusula no lo hagas en el ámbito global, úsala en el ámbito más pequeño posible. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber por qué.
  - Mezclas Inglés y Español, decide en qué idioma quieres redactar tu código.
- Problemas de uso:

  - Tu clase `matriz` no inicializa valores en el constructor por defecto, dejando sus variables miembro sin inicializar.
  - Devuelves tu clase `matriz` por copia en el operador de multiplicación; al copiar la matriz local en el retorno del operador, cuando finalice el operador se borrarán los datos a los que la copia apunta.
  - Si vas a devolver instancias de `matriz` por copia, necesitarás un constructor de movimiento.
- Problemas de diseño:

  - No tiene sentido construir una matriz sin especificar su tamaño, por lo que el constructor por defecto debería ser borrado.
  - La obtención de datos de un objeto suele hacerse creando un operador `std::istream &operator>>`, en todo caso, el rellenado de datos no tiene sentido que forme parte de la clase `matriz` y debería estar fuera de su lógica.
  - Mostrar datos de un objeto suele hacerse creando un operador `std::ostream &operator<<`, en todo caso, no tiene sentido que un objeto reciba un puntero a sus propios (o ajenos) datos internos para mostrarlos.
  - Los operadores aritméticos suelen definirse como funciones libres.
  - Falta la versión constante del operador de acceso a datos de la matriz (`operator()(int, int)`).
- Problemas de concepto:

  - La [multiplicación de matrices](https://www.ditutor.com/matrices/multiplicacion_matrices.html) implica que la matriz resultante debe tener las filas del operador izquierdo y las columnas del operador derecho, ni siquiera tienes en cuenta eso en el operador de multiplicación.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior...

#### Propuesta.

Tener un doble puntero para hacer una matriz bidimensional es poco práctico, difícil de mantener y propenso a errores. Además puede dar lugar a problemas de rendimiento pues es más eficiente que la memoria esté anexa (y no hay garantías de que vaya a ser así pidiendo memoria por cada fila).

Para evitar el problema anterior, lo ideal sería usar un espacio de una dimensión y simular las dos dimensiones y evitar toda la gestión manual de memoria, por lo tanto un `std::vector<double>` sería el mejor substituto para tu doble puntero, pero si *quieres* mantener el puntero, lo mejor será usar un puntero inteligente [`std::unique_ptr` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
class Matriz
{
    int filas{}, columnas{};
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> valores{};

    friend Matriz operator*(const Matriz &, const Matriz &);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Matriz &);

public:

    Matriz() = delete;

    Matriz(int filas, int columnas) :
        filas{filas},
        columnas{columnas},
        valores(std::make_unique<double[]>(filas * columnas))
    {}

    Matriz(Matriz &&matriz) {
        std::swap(filas, matriz.filas);
        std::swap(columnas, matriz.columnas);
        std::swap(valores, matriz.valores);
    }

    Matriz &operator=(const std::initializer_list<double> &datos) {
        std::copy(std::begin(datos), std::end(datos), std::begin(valores));
        return *this;
    }
    double &operator ()(int x, int y) {
        return valores[y * columnas + x];
    }
    double operator ()(int x, int y) const {
        return valores[y * columnas + x];
    }
    int Filas() const {
        return filas;
    }
    int Columnas() const {
        return columnas;
    }
};
```

En el código anterior hemos eliminado el constructor por defecto (`Matriz() = delete;`) de manera que estará prohibido crear matrices sin tamaño, todas las variables miembro tienen un inicializador por defecto (al añadirles las llaves `{}` al definirlas) y el doble puntero a `double` ahora es un puntero inteligente.

Para pasar de una  dos dimensiones, puedes consultar el operador de acceso (que ahora también dispone de una versión constante):

```
valores[y * columnas + x]
```

Siendo `y` las filas (vertical) y `x` las columnas (horizontal). He añadido un operador de asignación que recibe un [`std::initializer_list` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) que permite asignar valores así:

```
Matriz a(1, 2), b(2, 1);

a = {2., -1.};
b = {3., 5.};
```

Ten en cuenta que no se está verificando que la cantidad de elementos de la  `std::initializer_list`
 sea igual a la cantidad de elementos de la matriz (eso ya queda como mejora por tu parte). En cuanto a la función de multiplicación, la he definido como una función externa:

```
Matriz operator*(const Matriz &a, const Matriz &b) {
    Matriz resultado(a.Filas(), b.Columnas());

    for (int indice = 0, total = resultado.Filas() * resultado.Columnas(); indice != total; ++indice)
    {
        auto x = indice % resultado.Columnas();
        auto y = indice / resultado.Filas();
        auto valorxy = 0;

        for (int celda = 0; celda != a.Filas(); ++celda)
            valorxy += (a(celda, y) * b(x, celda));

        resultado(x, y) = valorxy;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Como puedes ver, la matriz resultante tiene tantas filas como el primer operando y tantas columnas como el segundo (detalle que tú pasabas por alto). Además estoy usando un índice único y aprovechando el propio operador de acceso de la matriz para acceder y asignar valores, lo que hace que el código sea mucho más legible. El resultado se devuelve por copia y la copia se hace correctamente al haber definido un constructor de movimiento. La función anterior tampoco está comprobando que las matrices sean multiplicables, eso ya queda a tu criterio.

En cuanto a mostrar los datos, la función es también externa:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Matriz &matriz) {
    for (int y = 0; y < matriz.Filas(); ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < matriz.Columnas(); ++x)
        {
            o << matriz(x, y) << ' ';
        }
        o << '\n';
    }

    return o;
}
```

Al sacar de la clase estas funciones, el código de la propia clase queda más claro. Con esta propuesta tu `main` podría parecerse a:

```
int main()
{
    Matriz m1(2, 1), m2(1, 2);

    m1 = {2.,
          -1.};
    m2 = {3., 5.};

    std::cout << m1 * m2;

    return 0;
}
```

Que debería dar el resultado esperado.