# ¿Cómo soluciono el error ...does not name a type en C++?

Tags: c++, lista, estructuras-de-datos, template

Estoy haciendo un juego en C++, el cual maneja estructuras de datos creadas por mi. La clase `Jugador` tiene una lista enlazada, la cual tiene un *template* y le pase la otra clase `Prendas` (Ya que es una lista de prendas).
El problema es que al declarar la lista, le muestra el error de `'Lista' does not name a type.`

El error se presenta en la clase `Jugador`, en la declaración `Lista<Prenda> prendas;`

Este es mi codigo:

Clase Lista:

```
#ifndef LISTA_H
#define LISTA_H
#include "Nodo.h"
#include <stdexcept>

template <class T>
class Lista : private Nodo<T>
{
    public:
        Lista();
        ~Lista();
        void agregar(T *obj);
        //AGREGA ANTES DE LA LISTA DEL PRINCIPIO
        void agregarPrincipio(T *obj) throw(std :: out_of_range);
        bool estaVacia();
        T *obtener(int index);
        int tamanio();
        bool eliminar(int index);
        void agregar(T *obj, int index);
        double SumatoriaTotal();
    protected:
    private:
        void agregarInicio(T *t);
        void agregarSiguiente(T *t);
        void agregarConEvaluacion(int &contaux, Nodo<T> *aux, Nodo<T> *punteroAnterior, int &index, T *obj);
        void eliminarCabecera(Nodo<T> *aux);
        bool eliminarNodosIntermedios(Nodo<T> *aux, Nodo<T> *puntAnterior, int contAuxiliar, int index);
        bool eliminarUltimo(Nodo<T> *aux, int &contAuxiliar, Nodo<T> *puntAnterior, int index);
    public:
        Nodo<T> *cab;
};
#endif
```

Clase Jugador:

```
#ifndef JUGADOR_H
#define JUGADOR_H
#include <string>
#include "Prenda.h"
#include "Lista.h"
using namespace std;
class Jugador
{
    public:
        int id;
        string nombre;
        string genero;
        Lista<Prenda> prendas;//AQUI SE PRESENTA EL ERROR
        Jugador(int id, string nombre, string genero);
        ~Jugador();
        void crearPrendas();
        static Prenda *asignarPrenda(int prenda);
        bool tienePrendas();
        int quitarPrimeraPrenda();
    protected:
};

#endif
```

Clase Prenda:

```
#include <string>
#ifndef PRENDA_H
#define PRENDA_H
using namespace std;
class Prenda
{
    public:
        int id;
        string prenda;
        Prenda(int id, string prenda);
        Prenda();
        ~Prenda();
    protected:
};

#endif
```

Obviamente, los métodos están ya declarados en el archivo `.cpp` correspondiente a cada clase.
Gracias.

Comment: Falta la cabecera de `Nodo`

Comment: No entiendo, porque clase Lista extiende la clase Nodo<T>, yo crearía dos atributos en la clase Lista de tipo Node<T>, uno llamado primero y otro llamado ultimo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los *templates* (`Lista` en este caso) deben poseer la *definición* en el mismo `.h`, esto es debido a que el compilador [los utiliza para generar la clase actual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) (es decir, `Lista` no es una clase, sino una plantilla con la cual crear una clase, pero `Lista<Prenda>` **si** es una clase).

Existen diversos trucos y *hacks* para poder definir los templates en un archivo `.cpp` por separado, pero la práctica recomendada (y utilizada por todas las bibliotecas grandes de C++ como Boost) es mover la definición al `.h`. En éste caso, es suficiente con mover el contenido de tu archivo `.cpp` al final del `.h` (sin incluir el `#include` que seguramente tienes al principio!). Un ejemplo sencillo de esto es:

```
#ifndef EJEMPLO
#define EJEMPLO

template<typename T>
class Ejemplo {
public:
    // Lo común es declarar los métodos dentro de
    // la misma clase:
    void hacer_algo(T valor) {
        valor.metodo();
    }

    // También puedes definirlos fuera de la clase:
    T hacer_otra_cosa();
};

// Nota como en la definición se escribe `Ejemplo<T>` en vez
// de simplemente `Ejemplo`.
template<typename T>
T Ejemplo<T>::hacer_otra_cosa() {
    return T(0);
}

#endif
```

Recuerda que esto solo aplica a los templates: si defines una clase normal en el archivo `.h` podrías causar un error de multiples definiciones de la misma clase!

Por último, te recomiendo [no utilizar `using namespace std`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%c3%a9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%c3%a1ctica) y preferir los contenedores estándares (como `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::list` y otros) antes que crear los tuyos.

Comment: Es decir que en vez de utilizar .cpp y .h combinados, utilizar un archivo para todo? En este caso recomiendas este archivo con la extension .h

Comment: @ElPapu Solamente si es un template! Las clases normales, funciones y demás si deberían estar separados en `.cpp` y `.h`.