# ¿Cómo ordeno numeros?, quiero que el ciclo "for" vaya de derecha a izquierda

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98, ordenamiento

Quiero ordenar numeros, con un ciclo "for", pero quisiera que el ciclo ordenando en pares de derecha a izquierda.
De antemano gracias a todos los que respondan.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int arreglo[3] = {4,2,1};
    int i, var_aux;

    for(i=3; i<3; i--)
    {
      if(arreglo[i] < arreglo[i-1])
        {
            var_aux = arreglo[i];
            arreglo[i] = arreglo[i-1];
            arreglo[i-1] = var_aux;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << arreglo[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for( i = 3; i < 3; i-- )` Eso no se va a ejecutar nunca; ¿ no será `i > 0` ?

Comment: La condición del bucle debe ser: (i=3; i>0; --i)

Answer (score 2):

> quiero que el ciclo “for” vaya de derecha a izquierda

Mala suerte, `for` no entiende eso de derecha e izquierda. El sentido es algo que le proporcionas tu al usuario, ya que el `for` únicamente es capaz de repetir un código un número determinado de veces.

Así que, siendo correctos, digamos que lo que pretendes es recorrer el array a la inversa. Bien, en C++ los índices empiezan en 0, luego si un array tiene, por ejemplo, 3 elementos, el último índice válido será 2 y no 3, luego tu `for` ya empieza teniendo cosas raras:

```
for(i=3; i<3; i--)
//    ^ Debería ser 2
```

Por otro lado, si recorres el array a la inversa, la condición del bucle debería ser que el valor de `i` sea mayor o igual a 0, ya que la secuencia que pretendes reproducir es `2, 1, 0`... el condicional del bucle también está mal

```
for(i=2; i<3; i--)
//       ^^^ Debería ser i>=0
```

Y con eso el bucle ya estaría arreglado... o no... vamos a echar un vistazo a las instrucciones que se ejecutan en el bucle:

```
var_aux = arreglo[i];
arreglo[i] = arreglo[i-1];
arreglo[i-1] = var_aux;
```

Con las condiciones que hemos puesto, `i` se moverá en el rango de valores `2..0`, lo cual es correcto... pero `i-1` se moverá en el rango `1..-1` y eso no pinta tan bien. No debemos dejar que ningún índice acceda a elementos que no pertenecen al array, así que podemos optar por reducir el rango de iteración:

```
for(i=2; i>0; i--)
```

Ahora, `i` se moverá en `2..1`, mientras que `i-1` lo hará en `1..0`. Ya no hay accesos fuera del array.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar un [iterador inverso](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend):

```
for (auto i = rbegin(arreglo), e = rend(arreglo) - 1; i != e; ++i)
{
    if (*i < *(i + 1))
    {
        swap(*i, *(i + 1));
    }
}
```

También he usado la utilidad [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) para simplificar el código. El iterador `i` apunta al final del arreglo (que es el principio si lo recorremos en sentido inverso) mientras que el iterador `e` apunta al anterior del final del arreglo (que es el primer elemento si lo recorremos en sentido inverso).

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- La cabecera `<stdlib.h>` es de [c](/questions/tagged/c) no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). No deberías usar en C++ cabeceras de C, si realmente necesitas usarlas (que rara vez será el caso) deberías usar la cabecera adaptada a C++ que en este caso sería `<cstdlib>`(sin extensión y con `c` como prefijo) lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más del tema.
- No usas la cabecera `<stdlib.h>` para nada. Además de que no deberías estar incluyendo esa cabecera, no usas ninguna de las herramientas que te ofrece, así que la estás incluyendo sin motivo. No la incluyas.
- No es necesaria la cláusula `using namespace std;` pues tan sólo es una ayuda a la escritura; no pasa nada por usarla pero si la usas procura que sea en el ámbito más pequeño posible; lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber más del tema.
- Procura favorecer el pre-decremento (o incremento) frente al post-decremento (o incremento), lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber más del tema.