# ¿Como hacer que programa entienda mis espacios como parte de la cadena de caracteres "string"?

Tags: c++, string, caracteres

Quiero hacer que cuando yo esté leyendo mi variable tipo `string` los espacios que yo inserte en el sean parte de la cadena, y no lo interprete como que voy a insertar el valor de otra variable.

Ejemplo:

```
string cadena;
int n;
cin>>cadena;
cin>>n;
```

Al momento de leer `cadena` e insertar un espacio quiero que ese espacio sea parte del `string` y el programa no lo interprete como que voy a leer `n` que es una variable de tipo entero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para leer los espacios tienes que usar la función `std::getline`:

```
std::getline(std::cin, cadena);
```

Ahora bien, a la hora de mezclar `std::cin` y `std::getline` hay que tener en cuenta un detalle tonto pero importante y es que `std::cin` **no elimina** los saltos de línea. Así que entre una llamada a `cin` y otra a `getline` es probable que debas usar `std::cin.ginore()` para eliminar el salto de línea.

```
int entero1, entero2;
std::string cadena1, cadena2;

std::cin >> entero1;
std::cin >> entero2; // No hace falta llamar a ignore

std::cin.ignore(); // Eliminamos el salto de linea

std::getline(std::cin, cadena1);
std::getline(std::cin, cadena2); // No hace falta llamar a ignore
```

Comment: Si al principio del programa coloco "using namespace std;" no hace falta ponerlos en todo el programa cierto?

Comment: @Alfrediwis `using namespace` no es una buena práctica. Consulta esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460) para saber por qué.