# Violación de segmento ('core' genereado) Al desencolar un elemento

Tags: c++

Definición de Clase DobNode

```
#ifndef TnDOBNODE
#define TnDOBNODE
#include <iostream>

template <class Tn>
class DobNode{
    public:
        Tn element;
        DobNode<Tn>* next;
        DobNode<Tn>* prev;

        DobNode(Tn pElement, DobNode<Tn>* pNext = NULL, DobNode<Tn>* pPrev = NULL){
            element = pElement;
            next = pNext;
            prev = pPrev;
        }
        DobNode(DobNode<Tn>* pNext = NULL, DobNode<Tn>* pPrev = NULL){
            next = pNext;
            prev = pPrev;
        }
};
#endif
```

Definición de Clase Cola

```
#ifndef ECOLA
#define ECOLA
#include <iostream>
#include "DobNode.h"
using namespace std;
template <class E>
class Cola{
    public:
        DobNode<E> *front;
        DobNode<E> *rear;
        int tamano;
        Cola(){
            front = rear = NULL;
        }
        ~Cola() { clear(); }
        void clear(){
            while (front!=NULL){
                DobNode<E> *temp = front;
                front = front->prev;
                delete temp;
            delete front;
            }
        }
        void encolar(E elem){
            DobNode<E> *temp = new DobNode<E>(elem,rear);
            rear = temp;
        }
        E desencolar(){
            E elem = front->element;
            DobNode<E> *temp = front;
            front = front->prev;
            delete temp;
            tamano--;
            return elem;
        }
        E frente(){
            return front->element;
        }
        bool vacia(){
            return (rear==NULL);
        }       
};
#endif
```

Main

```
#include "Cola.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Cola<int> ColaInt;
    cout << "Cola Mundo\n";
    ColaInt.encolar(4);
    ColaInt.encolar(6);
    ColaInt.encolar(7);
    ColaInt.encolar(9);
    ColaInt.encolar(1);
    ColaInt.desencolar();
    return 0;
}
```

El código es diseñado en c++
Y compilado con g++

Me genera Violación de segmento al desencolar el elemento

Comment: Cual es la traza del error que te sale?

Comment: Implementas una clase `nodo` pensado para listas doblemente enlazadas pero luego implementas una lista enlazada... ¿Qué es lo que pretendes hacer exactamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falla al desencolar porque `Cola::front` es `NULL`, por lo tanto `front->element` genera una violación de segmento.

En ningún momento de tu código asignas valor a `Cola::front`, por lo que se queda con el valor asignado en constructor que es `NULL`. Al encolar, si no hay aún nodos, tanto el frontal como el trasero son el nuevo nodo, en caso contrario el nuevo nodo insertado debe transformarse en el frontal (`front`):

```
if (!front && !rear) {
    front = rear = new DobNode<E>(elem, front);
} else {
    DobNode<E> *nuevo = new DobNode<E>(elem, front);
    front->next = nuevo;
    front = nuevo;                
}
```

---

1. No incluyas cabeceras que no usas. Incluyes `<iostream>` en `"DobNode.h"`, `"Cola.h"` y `"main.cpp"` cuando sólo estás usando sus utilidades en el último de esos archivos.
2. No abuses de la cláusula `using namespace std;`, si usas dicha cláusula hazlo en el ámbito más pequeño posible **NUNCA** en un archivo de cabecera (`"Cola.h"`), lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber más.
3. Utiliza la lista de inicialización de los constructores o la inicialización-en-declaración para simplificar el código.
4. Ayúdate de alias de tipo para simplificar el código.
5. El literal de puntero nulo en C++ es `nullptr` no la macro `NULL`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha servido de mucho, excelentes los consejos express que me brindaste