# C++ : Dudas con librerias y clases

Tags: c++

¿Por qué cuando desarrollamos una clase se utilizan los `::` ej: `MiClase::Funcion(){}`?

¿Y cuando utilizamos una funcion de la libreria estandar de c++ tambien usamos `::` pero para hacer uso de la función?

¿Por qué algunas librerias como cstdlib no necesitan `std::` para funcionar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador cuatro puntos (`::`) es el operador de jerarquía en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>1</sup> y nos indica que el símbolo de la derecha, está subordinado jerárquicamente al símbolo de la izquierda:

```
A :: B; // B está contenido en A.
```

Las relaciones jerárquicas que puedes tener son a nivel de objeto, enumerado o espacio de nombres:

```
namespace Espacio_de_nombres
{
    struct Objeto
    {
        enum class Enumerado
        {
            Elemento
        };

        int entero;
        static float flotante; 
    };

    Objeto instancia;
    using Entero = int;
}
```

Por lo tanto:

```
// Un enumerado anidado en un objeto anidado en un espacio de nombres
std::cout << (int)Espacio_de_nombres::Objeto::Enumerado::Elemento;
// Un valor dentro de una instancia anidada en un espacio de nombres
std::cout << Espacio_de_nombres::instancia.entero;
// Un valor estático dentro de un objeto anidado en un espacio de nombres
std::cout << Espacio_de_nombres::Objeto::flotante;
// Un objeto anidado en un espacio de nombres
std::cout << &Espacio_de_nombres::instancia;
// Un alias anidado en un espacio de nombres.
Espacio_de_nombres::Entero x;
```

Ahora respondamos a las preguntas:

> ¿Por qué cuando desarrollamos una clase se utilizan los `::` ej: `MiClase::Funcion(){}`?

Porque `Funcion()` pertenece al objeto `MiClase`, si usas la función `Funcion()` fuera del ámbito del objeto necesitarás el nombre completo, mientras que dentro del objeto no es necesario:

```
// Declaración
struct MiClase
{
    int Funcion();
    int Otra_Funcion();
}

// Definición
int MiClase::Funcion()
//         ^^ <--- Necesitamos decir que 'Funcion' pertenece a 'MiClase'
{
    return Otra_Funcion();
//         ~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Estamos dentro de 'MiClase', no necesitamos el nombre completo
}

int MiClase::Otra_Funcion()
//         ^^ <--- Necesitamos decir que 'Otra_Funcion' pertenece a 'MiClase'
{
    return 42;
}
```

> ¿Y cuando utilizamos una funcion de la libreria estandar de c++ tambien usamos `::` pero para hacer uso de la función?

Cuando te refieres a un objeto dentro del espacio de nombres estándar (`std` es ***st***andar**d**) es necesario el nombre completo a no ser que digas que en un ámbito concreto vas a asumir el uso de dicho espacio de nombres:

```
std::string cadena = "Hola Mundo";
// ^^~~~~ <--- El tipo 'string' está dentro del espacio de nombres 'std'
std::cout << cadena;
// ^^~~~~ <--- El objeto 'cout' está dentro del espacio de nombres 'std'
auto a = std::toupper('a');
//          ^^~~~~~~~~ <--- La función 'toupper' está dentro del espacio de nombres 'std'
```

Si hubieses usado la cláusula `using namespace std` no te habría hecho falta escribir el nombre completo, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber más.

> ¿Por qué algunas librerías como cstdlib no necesitan std:: para funcionar?

La cabecera (que no librería) `cstdlib` es la cabecera `stdlib.h` de C adaptada al lenguaje C++. No pertenecen a la librería estándar de C++ y por ello podrían<sup>2</sup> no estar incluidas en el espacio de nombres estándar. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más.

---

<sup>1</sup>Es uno de los pocos operadores que no puede ser sobrecargado.

<sup>2</sup>En general, las cabeceras estándar tienen "*permitido*" publicar símbolos en el espacio de nombres global, pero en la práctica se suele evitar.

Answer (score 1):

Los librerias estandardos de C++ ponen sus funciones en namespace (espacio de nombres)

```
namespace std
{
void sort(...);
}
```

y para llamar una funcion de namespace se debe utilizar `std::sort` or "importar" todos los funciones de ese namespace con `using namespace std`.

Razon es que nombres de funciones de librerias estandardos son muy comunes y pueden significar muchas cosas; namespaces permiten a programadores hacer su propios implementaciones de `sort`, `max`, etc. sin tener conflictos de nombres.

Los funciones de `cstdlib` no estan en namespaces porque deben ser compatibles con C que no los tiene.