# Como puedo acceder a los arrays de 3x3 que conforman una matriz de 9x9?

Tags: c++, array, array-bidimensional

El propósito del programa ( C++ ) es leer de teclado un array de 9x9 y decir si se trata de una tablero sudoku. Los requisitos para que un array sea sudoku son:

- En la fila del tablero no puede haber números repetidos (sin contar el 0)
- En cada columna no puede haber números repetidos (sin contar el 0)
- Un tablero sudoku se divide en 9 regiones de 3x3. En una misma región no puede haber números repetidos. (adjunto ejemplo abajo).

Mi problema es que no se como hacer para comprobar esta ultima opción, ya que he tratado de hacerlo pero no funciona de la manera en que lo he hecho. (adjunto tb el código). Adjunto también la captura del error que me da.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=9;
typedef array <int,MAX> Filas;
typedef array <Filas,MAX> Sudoku;

void leersudoku (Sudoku& m)
{
    cout<<"Introduzca un tableto de sudoku de "<<MAX<<"x"<<MAX<<": "<<endl;
    for (int f=0; f<int(m.size()); ++f)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<int(m[f].size()); ++c)
        {
            cin>>m[f][c];
        }
    }
}

bool repeticionfila (const Sudoku& m, int f)
{
    bool control=true;

    for (int c=0; c<int(m[f].size())-1; ++c)
    {
         if ((m[f][c]==m[f][c+1])&&(m[f][c]!=0))
         {
             control=false;
         }
    }

    return control;
}

bool repeticioncolumna (const Sudoku& m, int c)
{
    bool control=true;

    for (int f=0; c<int(m[f].size())-1; ++f)
    {
         if ((m[f][c]==m[f+1][c])&&(m[f][c]!=0))
         {
             control=false;
         }
    }

    return control;
}

bool comprobarconresto (const Sudoku& m, int f, int c, int j)
{
    int cnt=m[f][c];
    bool control=true;

    for (int f=0; f<j; ++f)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<j; ++c)
        {
            if ((m[f][c]==cnt)&&(m[f][c]!=0))
            {
                control=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return control;
}

bool comprobarmatrizespecficica (const Sudoku& m, int f, int c, int j)
{
    bool control=true;

    for (int x=f; x<j; ++x)
    {
        for (int y=c; y<j; ++y)
        {
            if(comprobarconresto(m,x,y,j)==false)
            {
                control=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return control;
}


void comprobarvalido (const Sudoku& m)
{
    bool es_valido=true;
    //--------------------------------------
    for (int f=0; f<int(m.size()); ++f)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<int(m[f].size()); ++c)
        {
            if ((m[f][c]<0)||(m[f][c]>9))
            {
                es_valido=false;
            }
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------
    for (int f=0; f<int(m.size()); ++f)
    {
        if (repeticionfila(m,f)==false)
        {
            es_valido=false;
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------
    for (int c=0; c<int(m[0].size()); ++c)
    {
        if(repeticioncolumna(m,c)==false)
        {
            es_valido=false;
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------
    for (int i=0; i<=2; ++i)
    {
        for (int f=3*i; f<int(m.size())-(6-3*i); ++f)
        {
            for (int c=3*i; c<int(m.size())-(6-3*i); ++c)
            {
                if(comprobarmatrizespecficica(m,f,c,int(m.size())-(6-3*i))==false)
                {
                    es_valido=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------

    if (es_valido==true)
    {
        cout<<"Este tablero de sudoku es valido"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Este tablero de sudoku no es valido"<<endl;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    Sudoku m;
    leersudoku(m);
    comprobarvalido(m);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No-respuesta: usar variables como `c`, `m` con nombres que no dicen nada hace mucho más difícil que modifiques, compartas o mantengas el código. Procura usar nombres más significativos. Lo otro, al validar cada fila estás preincrementando el valor de la variable en los ciclos; posiblemente ahí intentas leer la posición 9 que no existe (vas de 0 a 8)

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate en la función `repeticioncolumna`:

```
bool repeticioncolumna(const Sudoku &m, int c) {
    bool control = true;

    for (int f = 0; c < int(m[f].size()) - 1; ++f) {
        if ((m[f][c] == m[f + 1][c]) && (m[f][c] != 0)) {
            control = false;
        }
    }

    return control;
}
```

Tienes la variable `f`, que incrementas cada vuelta. Hasta aquí bien. Pero, date
cuenta de la condición que le colocaste al `for`:

```
    c < int(m[f].size()) - 1
```

Tu no cambias `c` en ningún momento. Entonces si inicialmente `c` es menor que
`8`, la condición del loop siempre sera verdadera, hasta que `f` llegue a `9`,
donde trataras de acceder a memoria fuera de `m`, que causara el error que
tienes.

## Notas

Estas no tienen que ver mucho con tu problema, pero si creo que te pueden ser de
utilidad.

#### `AdressSanitizer`

Los problemas de memoria son difíciles de resolver, y puede tomar mucho tiempo.
El origen de este lo encontré relativamente rápido porque use el `ASAN`, seria
bueno que investigaras como utilizarlo en CodeBlocks (Que es lo que parece que
usas).

En este caso el resultado de usar el `ASAN` es:

```
==1196==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x0038f4eff7e4 at pc 0x7ff6b9261438 bp 0x0038f4eff4e0 sp 0x0038f4eff528
READ of size 4 at 0x0038f4eff7e4 thread T0
    #0 0x7ff6b9261437 in repeticioncolumna(class std::array<class std::array<int, 9>, 9> const &, int) (C:\Users\pabsa\temp\a.exe+0x140001437)
    #1 0x7ff6b9261a6f in comprobarvalido(class std::array<class std::array<int, 9>, 9> const &) (C:\Users\pabsa\temp\a.exe+0x140001a6f)
    #2 0x7ff6b9261da8 in main (C:\Users\pabsa\temp\a.exe+0x140001da8)
    #3 0x7ff6b92dadbf in invoke_main d:\A01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
    #4 0x7ff6b92dadbf in __scrt_common_main_seh d:\A01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
    #5 0x7ffd8e8e7033  (C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x180017033)
    #6 0x7ffd8ea22650  (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x180052650)

Address 0x0038f4eff7e4 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 356 in frame
    #0 0x7ff6b9261c5f in main (C:\Users\pabsa\temp\a.exe+0x140001c5f)

  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 356) 'm' <== Memory access at offset 356 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp, SEH and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow (C:\Users\pabsa\temp\a.exe+0x140001437) in repeticioncolumna(class std::array<class std::array<int, 9>, 9> const &, int)
```

Nos dice que el error esta en `repeticioncolumna`, y que es en el acceso a la
variable `m`.

#### `for` de rango

En C++11 tenemos los [Range-based for
loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). Estos pueden
ayudarte a simplificar bastante tu código. Por ejemplo:

```
void leersudoku(Sudoku &m) {
    cout << "Introduzca un tableto de sudoku de " << MAX << "x" << MAX << ": "
         << endl;
    for (int f = 0; f < int(m.size()); ++f) {
        for (int c = 0; c < int(m[f].size()); ++c) {
            cin >> m[f][c];
        }
    }
}
```

Puede pasar a ser:

```
void leersudoku(Sudoku &m) {
    cout << "Introduzca un tableto de sudoku de " << MAX << "x" << MAX << ": "
         << endl;
    for (auto& fila : m) {
        for (auto& columna : fila) {
            cin >> columna;
        }
    }
}
```

Que es mucho mas limpio y fácil de leer. Ademas, con estos fijo que no te pasas
del tamaño de `m`.

#### Convenciones

- Nombres que sean todo mayúsculas tendrían que estar reservados para los
  macros. `MAX` tendría que ser en minúscula, y en vez de `const` tendría que
  ser `constexpr`.
- Seria bueno que uses el `snake_case` consistentemente a lo largo de tu
  código, lo hará mas fácil de leer.
- `typedef` es de C, si programas en C++ seria bueno que usaras `using`. En
  lugar de:

  ```
  typedef array<int, MAX>   Filas;
  typedef array<Filas, MAX> Sudoku;
  ```

  tendría que ser:

  ```
  using Filas = array<int, MAX>;
  using Sudoku = array<Filas, MAX>;
  ```

  Que es mas fácil de leer.
- Usar `using namespace std;` [no es la mejor
  idea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%c3%a9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%c3%a1ctica).
  Mientras aprendes esta bien, pero no lo hagas una costumbre.

Comment: @Pablochchaes Perfecto gracias. Ya lo he cambiado, sin embargo sigue sin funcionarme. Que podría hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar un desplazamiento (*offset*). Sabes que una sub-cuadrícula se desplazará (como mucho) tres posiciones en vertical y horizontal; así pues dado un `Sudoku` y unas coordenadas:

```
bool RepetidosEn3x3(const Sudoku &s, int fila, int columna)
{
    // Usaremos el std::set para buscar repetidos.
    std::set valores{};

    // Desplazamiento vertical
    for (int y = 0; y != 3; ++y)
    {
        // Desplazamiento horizontal
        for (int x = 0; x != 3; ++x)
        {
            auto insercion = valores.insert(s[fila + y][columna + x]);
            if (!insercion.second)
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```