# ¿Cómo hacer un traductor inglés-español en C++?

Tags: c++, traducción

Buen día, necesito hacer un traductor de inglés-español en C++, que tenga un menú que permita escoger traducir de un idioma al otro. Esto es lo que llevo por ahora (está de sobra decir que tiene errores y le faltan cosas). Por ahora quiero que funcione lo del menú y que se haga la "traducción".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

struct lang{
        char english[20];
        char spanish[20];
        };
lang wordslist[50]={"CAT","GATO","DOG","PERRO","ENGLISH","INGLES","SPANISH","ESPANOL","FISH","PEZ","TURTLE","TORTUGA","BEAR","OSO","RABBIT","CONEJO","HELLO","HOLA","TREE","ARBOL","BLUE","AZUL","COLOR","COLOR","RED","ROJO","SMALL","PEQUENO","COMPUTER","COMPUTADORA","NUMBER","NUMERO","WORD","PALABRA","APPLE","MANZANA","GOODBYE","ADIOS","ORANGE","NARANJA","FRUIT","FRUTA","LEMON","LIMON","MOUSE","RATON","PLAY","JUGAR","WRITE","ESCRIBIR","HOUSE","CASA","PHONE","TELEFONO","SPEAK","HABLAR","SCHOOL","ESCUELA","BOOK","LIBRO"};
char word[50];
int i;

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    gotoxy(7,5);
    printf("ENGLISH-SPANISH TRANSLATOR");
    gotoxy(14,7);
    printf("Introduzca la palabra en espanol a traducir --> ");
    gets(word);
    clrscr();
    int x=strcmp(word,wordslist[i]);
    for (i=0;i<=50;i++)
    {
        if (x<0)
        {
            cout<<wordslist[i].spanish<<" ";
            cout<<wordslist[i].english<<" ";
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Creo que el error principal está en el strcmp, aparece un error y no puedo comparar las dos cadenas (creo que se llaman así, soy nuevo en la programación, el profesor no nos ha explicado muy bien muchas cosas, por ello estoy aquí). Por si preguntan, el compilador es Turbo C++.

Le agredeceré mucho a quien me pudiera ayudar. Si faltaron datos diganmelo.

Comment: Programáticamente lo más sencillo que conseguirás es una traducción literal, que puedes hacer con un diccionario o un mecanismo similar como el que usas. Si quieres un traductor fiable sugiero que crees una IA.

Comment: Si, lo que busco hacer es uno sencillo de traducción literal como diccionario.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster
Recomiendo `using namespace std;` luego de la declaracion de las librerias a usar para tener que evitar poner "`std::*tipo_de_dato*`" cada vez que se use algo que necesite el `namespace std`. @Historia en Mapas
Recomiendo que visites este sitio por si te interesa adentrarte mas en el ejecicio. [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) es un IDE poderoso escrito en C++, disponible para c++, python, java y c#, que te facilitaria el trabajo para el ejercicio del diccionario que mencionas arriba y para muchas cosas mas. Saludos

Comment: Por otra parte, _recomiendo_ que leas [¿Por qué el usar "using namespace std;" se considera mala práctica?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460)

Comment: En pocas palabras, es malo usar `using namespaces std;` porque puede haber colisión de nombres. Si se va a usar, es recomendable que se haga en lugares de poco alcance. Por ejemplo, dentro de una función.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que sucede es que has puesto la comparación **fuera** del bucle, luego solo se va a ejecutar una vez ... además, en ese punto `i` no está inicializada, luego puede valer cualquier cosa.

No estaría de más que eliminases la declaración global de `i`. Las variables deben tener una vida lo más pequeña posible. Esto ayuda a evitar ciertos errores en el código.

Otro detalle: Si el array tiene 50 elementos, tienes que iterar de 0 a 49. Si lo haces de 0 a 50 entonces estarás intentando acceder a 51 elementos ...

El código, corregido, podría quedar así:

```
for (int i=0; i<50; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(word,wordslist[i].spanish) == 0)
    {
        cout<<wordslist[i].spanish<<" ";
        cout<<wordslist[i].english<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 3):

> Creo que el error principal está en el strcmp

No, los errores de código ya los ha señalado [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/538292/2742), yo te voy a señalar los errores de diseño:

- En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), para trabajar con texto se usa el objeto `std::string`, disponible al incluir la cabecera `<string>`, este objeto tiene métodos internos para comparar, copiar y gestionar texto sin confiar en herramientas de [c](/questions/tagged/c) como `strcmp`.
- Si estás trabajando con C++, **NO** debes usar las cabeceras de C, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48305/2742) para saber más del tema.
- En C++ se usan flujos de datos para leer y escribir en consola, no uses herramientas de C como `printf` o `gets`.
- No necesitas inicializar a mano los datos si tus datos son estáticos, úsalos directamente.
- La función `main` debe devolver `int`.

Siguiendo los consejos anteriores, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

struct en_to_es {
    std::string english;
    std::string spanish;
};

std::list<en_to_es> wordslist {
    {"CAT","GATO"},
    {"DOG","PERRO"},
    {"ENGLISH","INGLES"},
    {"SPANISH","ESPANOL"},
    {"FISH","PEZ"},
    {"TURTLE","TORTUGA"},
    {"BEAR","OSO"},
    {"RABBIT","CONEJO"},
    {"HELLO","HOLA"},
    {"TREE","ARBOL"},
    {"BLUE","AZUL"},
    {"COLOR","COLOR"},
    {"RED","ROJO"},
    {"SMALL","PEQUENO"},
    {"COMPUTER","COMPUTADORA"},
    {"NUMBER","NUMERO"},
    {"WORD","PALABRA"},
    {"APPLE","MANZANA"},
    {"GOODBYE","ADIOS"},
    {"ORANGE","NARANJA"},
    {"FRUIT","FRUTA"},
    {"LEMON","LIMON"},
    {"MOUSE","RATON"},
    {"PLAY","JUGAR"},
    {"WRITE","ESCRIBIR"},
    {"HOUSE","CASA"},
    {"PHONE","TELEFONO"},
    {"SPEAK","HABLAR"},
    {"SCHOOL","ESCUELA"},
    {"BOOK","LIBRO"}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "ENGLISH-SPANISH TRANSLATOR";
    std::string palabra;
    std::getline(std::cin, palabra);

    auto found = std::find_if(wordslist.begin(), wordslist.end(),
        [&palabra](const en_to_es &dupla)
        {
            return dupla.english == palabra;
        });

    if (found == wordslist.end())
        std::cout << "No se traducir " << palabra;
    else
        std::cout << palabra << " es " << found->spanish << " en espanol";

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZRNT@MwEIbPya@wshIqUkF7hraS05o24MZZJxGC1QqFJC2WglPlQ3tA/PYyduxQerL1zMw74xnb@eFwlVeZ3B@Pv4TMq74o0UzUbdeU2fvC/WZAhNyfkqza143o3n64VaLtFq4L3n3eoVK@dPVL2aIP12m74uZmUAG@B8e325@0PWRS089bpQAGpTazIgv0v26KVjGl9@EtceJNvTVOmPc5VWDF1gAiwrklJFzTIN4ADWBHYoPjCIcDJmrLqOF3A4zIswFJyhNKACWMJ@kaG@wTzAGy2Obh2PcDVc2SheTe0g2hlAHcMGojE06UHOb@mNSnqUbPqSVLRhnXYmo1GcgKCGejeLzFlOpi/6QkZGPoNkoTMkSrLV4xbpOH6dbXJtiQsUePjCvpCFPsj644ivS5tzh8xqGla8ZW/pOudhUw201IEK4VDDHs7q3zHU91S2BNLKNky0JgNFDrwLYsjVU0h0FaFlH8BOgeWm4b8MiDhOiJLXngBxZvTPQSxzZJtIEhqJkRSu7Y2Jo4IvhBTQP7dFSNlxvG6CCbknFMPmMPukxftUlfSCE79J4JObl07W3O675Dsxmy1@zK3CuUQB9iCufh3tkdP2RV9tpklu7LrhKynAxyQk6twyVkdLK@q9Gu7mWB5ki77IQsXsRuMr6E69dyr2qafj@O61IWAFzH@Xth1P5N8lq2J@/xougPVXYJPnAWx2nKrm8k0vDaPE40n59U63zqisQOTUxB8/OMSu1nW8IatSXqmqzoc9EgT8FvybJqy/MQY9XRCOrUITrh1cJ8D8YmwQygrjxVlznAb/g7jkf1it0v)</kbd>.

Comment: Gracias por responder